# Favorite Django Tips & Features?

Tags: python, django, hidden-features

Inspired by the question series 'Hidden features of ...', I am curious to hear about your favorite Django tips or lesser known but useful features you know of.

- Please, include only one tip per answer.
- Add Django version requirements if there are any.

Answer (score 221):

I'm just going to start with a tip from myself :)

**Use os.path.dirname() in settings.py to avoid hardcoded dirnames.**

Don't hardcode path's in your settings.py if you want to run your project in different locations. Use the following code in settings.py if your templates and static files are located within the Django project directory:

```
# settings.py
import os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
...
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static")
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

Credits: I got this tip from the screencast '[Django From the Ground Up](http://thisweekindjango.com/screencasts/episode/10/django-ground-episodes-1-and-2/)'.

Comment: Hmm, I never thought of that... usually I downvote people who answer their own questions, but this one is actually useful.

Comment: You shouldn't downvote people that answer their own questions. It is encouraged, even if it is pre-determined.

Comment: This is such a good idea that I still have a hard time understanding why it's not default.  How many folks test and deploy on the same machine?

Comment: The leading slash in the 2nd argument to join() will cause those paths to be relative to the root.  ie /static/ /home/user/static/

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't a default.

Comment: This alleviates you from always type os.path.join() which gets annoying pretty fast: `j = lambda filename: os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, filename)`. Then you just need to type `j("static")`.

Comment: If you are on Windows then replace the backslashes:
os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates").replace('\\','/')

Comment: @Dominic, "When specifying the path, always use forward slashes, even on Windows (e.g. C:/homes/user/mysite/sqlite3.db)." from here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup

Comment: @Agnel - why? I do all my Django development on Windows (before deploying to a Linux box), and have never ever had a problem with just using the output of `os.path.join`. What problems might you expect me to see?

Comment: @Dominic, I must confess that I'm a newbie to Django... it's just what I read in the tutorial. You may be right.

Comment: If you really like to get this fixed in Django leave a comment to http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/694 asking core devs to reconsider the `wontfix` decision.

Comment: you should import os and not os.path a per the python documentation.

Comment: Note that if you have `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader` in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting, you don't really need to specific template_dirs at all.  It will automatically find templates if they are located in `appname/templates` for each app.

Comment: Alternative: `this_dir = lambda *x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)`

Answer (score 128):

Install [Django Command Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions) and [pygraphviz](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/) and then issue the following command to get a really nice looking Django model visualization:

```
./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project.png
```

Comment: Nice, couldn't get the pygraphviz to install correctly in windows, but can still covert from the dot file using graphviz.

Comment: I love sharing model diagrams with this definitely a +1

Comment: Is there an svg option for this?

Comment: output image seems to be busted now

Answer (score 119):

Use [django-annoying's](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home) `render_to` decorator instead of `render_to_response`.

```
@render_to('template.html')
def foo(request):
    bars = Bar.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/some/url/")
    else:
        return {'bars': bars}

# equals to
def foo(request):
    bars = Bar.objects.all()
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/some/url/")
    else:
        return render_to_response('template.html',
                              {'bars': bars},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Edited to point out that returning an HttpResponse (such as a redirect) will short circuit the decorator and work just as you expect.

Comment: How do U pass the request context?

Comment: @becomingGuru - it happens automatically.

Comment: This is fine, unless you are returning some HttpResponseRedirect()s and some render_to_response()s.  Then the redirects fail.

Comment: @becomingGuru the manual passing of request contexts is such a chore that one wonders why there was no builtin way to do it from the get-go.  It would be surprising if the problem weren't automatically solved.

Comment: Nice, they should add a direct_to decorator as well (equivalent to direct_to_response).

Comment: I don't like it. "Explicit is better than implicit". The decorator is not telling when exactly it is going to render_to.

Comment: Meh, I like the direct_to_template generic view better as a replacement for render_to_template in my views.

Comment: @Matthew Schinckel it actually doesn't mess up redirects - if you return an HttpResponse object it just passes it along without modifying it

Comment: I believe this approach is now redundant as of Django 1.3, see django.shortcuts.render() http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: @Dolph: it's still not quite the same. `return render(request, template)` versus `@render_to(template`. See the difference? django-annoying's `render_to` is taking the `request` from the arguments, django's `render` requires it to be passed.

Answer (score 101):

There's a set of custom tags I use all over my site's templates. Looking for a way to autoload it (DRY, remember?), I found the following:

```
from django import template
template.add_to_builtins('project.app.templatetags.custom_tag_module')
```

If you put this in a module that's loaded by default (your main urlconf for instance), you'll have the tags and filters from your custom tag module available in any template, without using `{% load custom_tag_module %}`.

The argument passed to `template.add_to_builtins()` can be any module path; your custom tag module doesn't have to live in a specific application. For example, it can also be a module in your project's root directory (eg. `'project.custom_tag_module'`).

Comment: @Steef, you just saved me loads of time/heartache/bytes, thanks.

Comment: Really nice. Thanks.
Also a repository of custom tags would be great to share stuff, dont you think?

Comment: That's great until someone else has to maintain your code. Think: "principle of least magic"

Answer (score 96):

[Virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#what-it-does) + Python = life saver if you are working on multiple Django projects and there is a possibility that they all don't depend on the same version of Django/an application.

Comment: Could you add some tutorial links for virtualenv with django?

Comment: @BozoJoe: Do this in your terminal: `virtualenv myNewEnv --no-site-packages`; `. myNewEnv/bin/activate`; `pip install django`; And it just works!

Answer (score 87):

Don't hard-code your URLs!

Use [url names](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) instead, and the [`reverse`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function to get the URL itself.

When you define your URL mappings, give names to your URLs.

```
urlpatterns += ('project.application.views'
   url( r'^something/$', 'view_function', name="url-name" ),
   ....
)
```

Make sure the name is unique per URL.

I usually have a consistent format "project-appplication-view", e.g. "cbx-forum-thread" for a thread view.

**UPDATE** (shamelessly stealing [ayaz's addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features/560111#560111)):

This name can be used in templates with the [`url` tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: I agree 100% on this one.  I started out using hard coded urls, and it bit me on a project when I changed the url format around a bit to accommodate some changes.  I took the time to go back and dig through everything and replace hard coded urls.  

My only big complaint is that url tag errors kill the whole page while hard coded only messes up the individual link.

Comment: This shouldn't be a hidden feature, this is best practice and the only way to fly.

Comment: @skyl It's hardly "the only way to fly".  I was at a Django dev sprint and Adrian Holovaty (one of the creators of Django) said he doesn't even use the `url` tag...   His stance is that urls shouldn't be changing anyway (if you want to be friendly to your users).

Comment: you can use this in templates, too, as in `{% url path.to.view.name arg1 arg2 %}` http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url

Comment: If you use jinja2, just add `reverse` like this `environment.filters['url'] = django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` and you can use it in your templates like so: `{{ 'view-name'|url(arg1, arg2)|e }}` (the "e" is needed to escape some characters for inclusion in HTML)

Answer (score 81):

Use [django debug toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar/). For example, it allows to view all SQL queries performed while rendering view and you can also view stacktrace for any of them.

Answer (score 79):

Don't write your own login pages.  If you're using django.contrib.auth.

The real, dirty secret is that if you're also using django.contrib.admin, and django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source is in your template loaders,  **you can get your templates free too!**

```
# somewhere in urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.auth',
    (r'^accounts/login/$','views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/logout/$','views.logout'),
)
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that we can reuse the admins login page. Thanks!

Answer (score 66):

### Context processors are awesome.

Say you have a different user model and you want to include
that in every response. Instead of doing this:

```
def myview(request, arg, arg2=None, template='my/template.html'):
    ''' My view... '''
    response = dict()
    myuser = MyUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
    response['my_user'] = myuser
    ...
    return render_to_response(template,
                              response,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Context processes give you the ability to pass any variable to your
templates. I typically put mine in `'my_project/apps/core/context.py`:

```
def my_context(request):
    try:
        return dict(my_user=MyUser.objects.get(user=request.user))
    except ObjectNotFound:
        return dict(my_user='')
```

In your `settings.py` add the following line to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'my_project.apps.core.context.my_context',
    ...
)
```

Now every time a request is made it includes the `my_user` key automatically.

### Also [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) win.

I wrote a blog post about this a few months ago so I'm just going to cut and paste:

Out of the box Django gives you several signals that are
incredibly useful. You have the ability to do things pre and
post save, init, delete, or even when a request is being
processed. So lets get away from the concepts and
demonstrate how these are used. Say we’ve got a blog

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(_('body'))
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So somehow you want to notify one of the many blog-pinging
services we’ve made a new post, rebuild the most recent
posts cache, and tweet about it. Well with signals you have
the ability to do all of this without having to add any
methods to the Post class.

```
import twitter

from django.core.cache import cache
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.conf import settings

def posted_blog(sender, created=None, instance=None, **kwargs):
    ''' Listens for a blog post to save and alerts some services. '''
    if (created and instance is not None):
        tweet = 'New blog post! %s' instance.title
        t = twitter.PostUpdate(settings.TWITTER_USER,
                               settings.TWITTER_PASSWD,
                               tweet)
        cache.set(instance.cache_key, instance, 60*5)
       # send pingbacks
       # ...
       # whatever else
    else:
        cache.delete(instance.cache_key)
post_save.connect(posted_blog, sender=Post)
```

There we go, by defining that function and using the
post_init signal to connect the function to the Post model
and execute it after it has been saved.

Comment: Django's Signals are a must-have feature for me these days, when comparing web frameworks.  Writing a loosely coupled forum, say, that can listen for, say, updates from a "signature" module, but not actually require that module to work, and that can also work with compatible modules implementing the same feature, is great.  I don't know why signals aren't more well known and popular.

Comment: Signals are very important to avoid tight coupling and code mess in general if we use some reusable apps in our project. You provided an excellent example for loose coupling of django apps, +1 for this.

Comment: Do you know if signals are async ?

Comment: "Say you have a different user model and you want to include that in every response." - Put the user into the [session](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/sessions/). That saves you a database hit for every request.

Comment: Signals' calls are synchronous. In my opinion, some sort of asynchronous job mechanism is more suitable for, say, publishing on Twitter/Facebook/etc (ie - rabbitmq), so users of out website don't hang on request.

Answer (score 58):

When I was starting out, I didn't know that there was a [Paginator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#topics-pagination), make sure you know of its existence!!

Answer (score 46):

Use [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) to jump into your code at any level and debug using the power of IPython.  Once you have installed IPython just put this code in wherever you want to debug:

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed; IPShellEmbed()()
```

Then, refresh the page, go to your runserver window and you will be in an interactive IPython window.

I have a snippet set up in TextMate so I just type ipshell and hit tab.  I couldn't live without it.

Comment: Better install `ipdb` and then just type `ipdb.set_trace()`

Comment: Or use Eclipse / PyDev's debugger.  :-)

Comment: import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() FTW!

Answer (score 43):

Run a development SMTP server that will just output whatever is sent to it (if you don't want to actually install SMTP on your dev server.)

command line:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

Comment: you can use console and file email backends in django 1.2 for the same purpose

Comment: outstanding! perfect for registration! +1

Comment: Alternative in Django 1.2 with settings: `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`   ..that will print the email to the `manage.py` output.

Answer (score 41):

From the [django-admin documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/):

If you use the Bash shell, consider installing the Django bash completion script, which lives in `extras/django_bash_completion` in the Django distribution. It enables tab-completion of `django-admin.py` and `manage.py` commands, so you can, for instance...

- Type `django-admin.py`.
- Press [TAB] to see all available options.
- Type `sql`, then [TAB], to see all available options whose names start with `sql`.

Comment: This is in by default in newer Ubuntu's at least. :-) I was amazed when it first came out of nowhere.

Answer (score 40):

The `./manage.py runserver_plus` facilty which comes with [django_extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) is truly awesome.

It creates an enhanced debug page that, amongst other things, uses the Werkzeug debugger to create interactive debugging consoles for each point in the stack (see screenshot).  It also provides a very useful convenience debugging method `dump()` for displaying information about an object/frame.

[image]

To install, you can use pip:

```
pip install django_extensions
pip install Werkzeug
```

Then add `'django_extensions'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in `settings.py` and start the development server with the new extension:

```
./manage.py runserver_plus
```

This will change the way you debug.

Answer (score 37):

I like to use the Python debugger pdb to debug Django projects.

This is a helpful link for learning how to use it: http://www.ferg.org/papers/debugging_in_python.html

Comment: This is a godsend. To give a little more info, just add this: "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" on any line of your code. Refresh your page. It will hang. Now go to your terminal window where you are running the development server. It should now be a interactive shell where you can access all variables as they are at that point in your code where you pasted the debug code.

Answer (score 37):

When trying to exchange data between Django and another application, `request.raw_post_data` is a good friend. Use it to receive and custom-process, say, XML data.

Documentation:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/

Answer (score 36):

Use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) alongside Django.

If you find the Django template language extremely restricting (like me!) then you don't have to be stuck with it. Django is flexible, and the template language is loosely coupled to the rest of the system, so just plug-in another template language and use it to render your http responses!

I use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/), it's almost like a powered-up version of the django template language, it uses the same syntax, and allows you to use expressions in if statements! no more making a custom if-tags such as `if_item_in_list`! you can simply say `%{ if item in list %}`, or `{% if object.field < 10 %}`.

But that's not all; it has many more features to ease template creation, that I can't go though all of them in here.

Comment: I use and enjoy Jinja2 as well, but I've found that there are some couplings to the "contrib" applications.  Particularly, the admin tool is pretty heavily tied to Django templates. Also, I had to recreate the login decorators in contrib.auth to be Jinja2 friendly, but not too hard.

Comment: Don't replace the template system with jinja2, just "add" it, don't remove the django templtes. Use Jinja2 for your own views, and let the admin interface continue to use the django template language.

Comment: I agree hartily with this.  Django's limited syntax is tolerable, most of the time, but when you get to the point of making custom tags and find out just how hard that actually is, Jinja2 is a breath of fresh air

Comment: Also, if you want to do *any* metaprogramming on template source, Jinja2 is much more pleasant, since you can directly access the AST of parsed templates. Walking the AST makes tasks like finding out which templates extend a base template, or listing the unbound variables in a template source block, almost trivially easy.

Comment: Thankfully in Django 1.2 the IF tag is alot smarter

Comment: Make sure to set TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False in settings.py.  For some reason TEMPLATE_DEBUG == True gives you cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 35):

Add `assert False` in your view code to dump debug information.

Comment: I think assert False is more intuitive =D

Comment: if you're running your project in the django dev server, use python's pdb module. It's a much more powerful way to debug:

import pdb; pdb.stack_trace()

Comment: pdb is very useful, you are likely to have your connections time out unless you're very fast at debugging.

Comment: I always use `5 / 0` myself. Why five? No idea.

Comment: @StephenPaulger really?  My browser (firefox /w firebug) seems content to wait several minutes for a response while I debug.

Comment: I'v always used raise ValueError("Debug") for this

Comment: I prefer the more satisfying: diaf

Answer (score 34):

This adds to the reply above about [Django URL names and reverse URL dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features/558401#558401).

The URL names can also be effectively used within templates. For example, for a given URL pattern:

```
url(r'(?P<project_id>\d+)/team/$', 'project_team', name='project_team')
```

you can have the following in templates:

```
<a href="{% url project_team project.id %}">Team</a>
```

Answer (score 27):

Since Django "views" only need to be callables that return an HttpResponse, you can easily create class-based views like those in Ruby on Rails and other frameworks.

There are several ways to create class-based views, here's my favorite:

```
from django import http

class RestView(object):
    methods = ('GET', 'HEAD')

    @classmethod
    def dispatch(cls, request, *args, **kwargs):
        resource = cls()
        if request.method.lower() not in (method.lower() for method in resource.methods):
            return http.HttpResponseNotAllowed(resource.methods)
        try:
            method = getattr(resource, request.method.lower())
        except AttributeError:
            raise Exception("View method `%s` does not exist." % request.method.lower())
        if not callable(method):
            raise Exception("View method `%s` is not callable." % request.method.lower())
        return method(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return http.HttpResponse()

    def head(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.content = ''
        return response
```

You can add all sorts of other stuff like conditional request handling and authorization in your base view.

Once you've got your views setup your urls.py will look something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from views import MyRestView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^restview/', MyRestView.dispatch),
)
```

Comment: FWIW, the django authors actually use class-based views in a few places, e.g. contrib.formtools: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/formtools/wizard.py

Comment: If you add a __call__ method you could create a class called RestfulResource and then have your urls.py point to instances.

Comment: New (Django 1.3?) generic views are class-based.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of using `render_to_response` to bind your context to a template and render it (which is what the Django docs usually show) use the generic view [`direct_to_template`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template). It does the same thing that `render_to_response` does but it also automatically adds RequestContext to the template context, implicitly allowing context processors to be used. You can do this manually using `render_to_response`, but why bother? It's just another step to remember and another LOC. Besides making use of context processors, having RequestContext in your template allows you to do things like:

```
<a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}images/frog.jpg">A frog</a>
```

which is very useful. In fact, +1 on generic views in general. The Django docs mostly show them as shortcuts for not even having a views.py file for simple apps, but you can also use them inside your own view functions:

```
from django.views.generic import simple

def article_detail(request, slug=None):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    return simple.direct_to_template(request, 
        template="articles/article_detail.html",
        extra_context={'article': article}
    )
```

Comment: Save even more LOC by using the @render_to decorator available in django-annoying. http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/

Comment: ..or use new `render` shortcut method from Django 1.3 (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Answer (score 20):

I don't have enough reputation to reply to the comment in question, but it's important to note that if you're going to use [Jinja](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_(template_engine)), it does NOT support the '-' character in template block names, while Django does. This caused me a lot of problems and wasted time trying to track down the very obscure error message it generated.

Comment: One note that may or may not be applicable to "obscure error messages from jinja".  Make sure to set TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False in settings.py.  For some reason this will give you meaningful errors from Jinja templates.

Answer (score 19):

`django.db.models.get_model` does allow you to retrieve a model without importing it.

James shows how handy it can be: ["Django tips: Write better template tags — Iteration 4 "](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/07/django-tips-write-better-template-tags/).

Comment: Nice :O! And here I was doing lazy imports whenever I had circular dependencies.

Answer (score 19):

The [webdesign app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/webdesign/#ref-contrib-webdesign) is very useful when starting to design your website.  Once imported, you can add this to generate sample text:

```
{% load webdesign %}
{% lorem 5 p %}
```

Comment: FYI, for anyone using Jinja2 instead of Django templates, you can do: {{ lipsum(5) }}

Answer (score 19):

Everybody knows there is a development server you can run with "manage.py runserver", but did you know that there is a development view for serving static files (CSS / JS / IMG) as well ?

Newcomers are always puzzled because Django doesn't come with any way to serve static files. This is because the dev team think it is the job for a real life Web server.

But when developing, you may not want to set up Apache + mod_wisgi, it's heavy. Then you can just add the following to urls.py:

```
(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/path/to/media'}),
```

Your CSS / JS / IMG will be available at www.yoursite.com/site_media/.

Of course, don't use it in a production environment.

Comment: I use this in dev mode, and just to make sure I don't forget to turn this off in production, I wrap that URL rule in a DEBUG only conditional.

Answer (score 18):

I learned this one from the documentation for the [sorl-thumbnails](http://code.google.com/p/sorl-thumbnail/) app. You can use the "as" keyword in template tags to use the results of the call elsewhere in your template.

For example:

```
{% url image-processor uid as img_src %}
<img src="{% thumbnail img_src 100x100 %}"/>
```

This is mentioned in passing in the Django templatetag documentation, but in reference to loops only. They don't call out that you can use this elsewhere (anywhere?) as well.

Comment: If a keyword as "as" can be used with a template-tag depends of this particular tag. It is not defined by django itself but by single tags, depending on their meaning. Have a look in the mentioned url-tag to see how "as" is used: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaulttags.py

Answer (score 16):

[django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/?from=olddocs#django-views-generic-list-detail-object-list) -- It provides all the logic & template variables for pagination (one of those I've-written-that-a-thousand-times-now drudgeries).  [Wrapping it](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter11/) allows for any logic you need.  This gem has saved me many hours of debugging off-by-one errors in my "Search Results" pages and makes the view code cleaner in the process.

Comment: You can find the new version of the book's chapter on Generic Views on http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter11/ . The one on the comment goes to the Django pre-1.0 version of the book (Django book 1.0)

Answer (score 16):

[PyCharm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a nice environment to code and especially debug, with built-in support for Django.

Answer (score 14):

Use [xml_models](http://djangorestmodel.sourceforge.net/) to create Django models that use an XML REST API backend (instead of a SQL one).  This is very useful especially when modelling third party APIs - you get all the same QuerySet syntax that you're used to.  You can install it from PyPI.

XML from an API:

```
<profile id=4>
    <email>joe@example.com</email>
    <first_name>Joe</first_name>
    <last_name>Example</last_name>
    <date_of_birth>1975-05-15</date_of_birth>
</profile>
```

And now in python:

```
class Profile(xml_models.Model):
    user_id = xml_models.IntField(xpath='/profile/@id')
    email = xml_models.CharField(xpath='/profile/email')
    first = xml_models.CharField(xpath='/profile/first_name')
    last = xml_models.CharField(xpath='/profile/last_name')
    birthday = xml_models.DateField(xpath='/profile/date_of_birth')

    finders = {
        (user_id,):  settings.API_URL +'/api/v1/profile/userid/%s',
        (email,):  settings.API_URL +'/api/v1/profile/email/%s',
    }

profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=4)
print profile.email
# would print 'joe@example.com'
```

It can also handle relationships and collections.  We use it every day in heavily used production code, so even though it's beta it's very usable.  It also has a good set of stubs that you can use in your tests.

(Disclaimer: while I'm not the author of this library, I am now a committer, having made a few minor commits)

Comment: interesting project, keep it up!

Answer (score 14):

Use database migrations. Use [South](http://south.aeracode.org).

Answer (score 13):

Just found this link: http://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/#table-of-contents - "Django Best Practices".

Comment: Interesting site, but all that jumping of the page up and down makes me cringe.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of evaluating whole queryset to check whether you got back any results, use .exists() in Django 1.2+ and .count() for previous versions.

Both exists() and count() clears order by clauses and retrieves a single integer from DB. However exists() will always return 1 where as count may return higher values on which limits will be applied manually. Source for [has_result](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L412) used in exists() and [get_count](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L377) used in count() for the curious.

Since they both return a single integer, there's no model instantiation, loading model attributes in memory and no large TextFields being passed between your DB and app.

If you have already evaluated the query, .count() computes len(cached_result) and .exists() computes bool(cached_result)

**Not efficient - Example 1**

```
books = Books.objects.filter(author__last_name='Brown')
if books:
    # Do something
```

**Not efficient - Example 2**

```
books = Books.objects.filter(author__last_name='Brown')
if len(books):
    # Do something
```

**Efficient - Example 1**

```
books = Books.objects.filter(author__last_name='Brown')
if books.count():
    # Do something
```

**Efficient - Example 2**

```
books = Books.objects.filter(author__last_name='Brown')
if books.exists():
    # Do something
```

Comment: Considering that DB interaction is the crust of most Django apps, even minor improvements such as this one make a big difference.

Answer (score 12):

If you make changes into model

```
./manage.py dumpdata appname > appname_data.json  
./manage.py reset appname
django-admin.py loaddata appname_data.json
```

Comment: It will do if you work alone. But if you work in a team and/or have fixtures you don't want to modify by hand - then use [South](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/South). It's the proper way to handle model modifications.

Answer (score 11):

Use [signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to add accessor-methods on-the-fly.

I saw this technique in [django-photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue): For any Size object added, the post_init signal will add the corresponding methods to the Image model.
If you add a site *giant*, the methods to retrieve the picture in giant resolution will be `image.get_giant_url()`.

The methods are generated by calling `add_accessor_methods` from the `post_init` signal:

```
def add_accessor_methods(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for size in PhotoSizeCache().sizes.keys():
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_size' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_size, size=size))
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_photosize' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_photosize, size=size))
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_url' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_url, size=size))
        setattr(self, 'get_%s_filename' % size,
                curry(self._get_SIZE_filename, size=size))
```

See the [source code of photologue.models](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/source/browse/trunk/photologue/models.py) for real-world usage.

Answer (score 11):

## Remove Database Access Information from settings.py

One thing I've done in my Django site's `settings.py` is load database access info from a file in `/etc`.  This way the access setup (database host, port, username, password) can be different for each machine, and sensitive info like the password isn't in my project's repository.  You might want to restrict access to the workers in a similar manner, by making them connect with a different username.

You could also pass in the database connection information, or even just a key or path to a configuration file, via environment variables, and handle it in `settings.py`.

For example, here's how I pull in my database configuration file:

```
g = {}
dbSetup = {}
execfile(os.environ['DB_CONFIG'], g, dbSetup)
if 'databases' in dbSetup:
    DATABASES = dbSetup['databases']
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            # ...
        }
    }
```

Needless to say, you need to make sure that the file in `DB_CONFIG` is not accessible to any user besides the db admins and Django itself.  The default case should refer Django to a developer's own test database.  There may also be a better solution using the `ast` module instead of `execfile`, but I haven't researched it yet.

Another thing I do is use separate users for DB admin tasks vs. everything else.  In my `manage.py`, I added the following preamble:

```
# Find a database configuration, if there is one, and set it in the environment.
adminDBConfFile = '/etc/django/db_admin.py'
dbConfFile = '/etc/django/db_regular.py'
import sys
import os
def goodFile(path):
    return os.path.isfile(path) and os.access(path, os.R_OK)
if len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] in ["syncdb", "dbshell", "migrate"] \
    and goodFile(adminDBConfFile):
    os.environ['DB_CONFIG'] = adminDBConfFile
elif goodFile(dbConfFile):
    os.environ['DB_CONFIG'] = dbConfFile
```

Where the config in `/etc/django/db_regular.py` is for a user with access to only the Django database with SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE, and `/etc/django/db_admin.py` is for a user with these permissions plus CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, and LOCK TABLES.  (The `migrate` command is from [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).)  This gives me some protection from Django code messing with my schema at runtime, and it limits the damage an SQL injection attack can cause (though you should still check and filter all user input).

(Copied from my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884249/django-celery-database-for-models-on-producer-and-worker/3884535#3884535))

Answer (score 9):

Instead of running the Django dev server on localhost, run it on a proper network interface. For example:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.110:8000
```

or

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then you can not only easily use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or another tool like HTTP Debugger (http://www.httpdebugger.com/) to inspect your HTTP headers, but you can also access your dev site from other machines on your LAN to test.

Make sure you are protected by a firewall though, although the dev server is minimal and relatively safe.

Comment: "Relatively" is a good word, once I exposed the built-in static assets serving to the outer word and regret it. While technically it's not devserver-related, it's within the same piece of code - Django, so I would extrapolate this experience to the devserver as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use `wraps` decorator in custom views decorators to preserve view's name, module and docstring. E.g.

```
try:
    from functools import wraps
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.functional import wraps  # Python 2.3, 2.4 fallback.

def view_decorator(fun):
    @wraps(fun)
    def wrapper():
        # here goes your decorator's code
    return wrapper
```

**Beware**: will not work on a class-based views (those with `__call__` method definition), if the author hasn't defined a `__name__` property. As a workaround use:

```
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs
...
    @wraps(fun, assigned=available_attrs(fun))
```

Answer (score 7):

The [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) is really fantastic. Not really a toolbar, it actually brings up a sidepane that tells you all sorts of information about what brought you the page you're looking at - DB queries, the context variables sent to the template, signals, and more.

Answer (score 6):

Using an 'apps' folder to organize your applications without editing PYTHONPATH

This has come handy when I want to organize my folders like this:

```
apps/
    foo/
    bar/
site/
settings.py
urls.py
```

without overwritting PYTHONPATH or having to add **apps** to every import like:

```
from apps.foo.model import *
from apps.bar.forms import *
```

In your settings.py add

```
import os
import sys
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))
```

and you are ready to go :-)

I saw this at http://codespatter.com/2009/04/10/how-to-add-locations-to-python-path-for-reusable-django-apps/

Answer (score 5):

[Render form via django template instead of as_(ul|table|p)()](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/TemplatedForm).

This article shows, how to use template to render CusstomForms instead of `as_p()`, `as_table()`...

To make it work change

- `from django import newforms as forms` **to** `from django import forms`
- `from django.newforms.forms import BoundField` **to** `from django.forms.forms import BoundField`

Answer (score 5):

Use **[djangorecipe](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe)** to manage your project

- If you're writing a new app, this recipe makes testing it outside of a project really easy
- It allows you to manage dependencies for a project (e.g. what version of some app it should depend on)

All you have to do to get started is this:

1. Create a folder for your new website (or library)
2. Create a buildout.cfg with following content in it:

   ```
   [buildout]
   parts=django

   [django]
   recipe=djangorecipe
   version=1.1.1
   project=my_new_site
   settings=development
   ```
3. Grab a bootstrap.py to get a local installation of buildout and place it within your directory. You can either go with the [official one](http://www.google.at/search?q=buidlout+bootstrap.py&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) (sorry, Markdown didn't like part of the full link :-/ ) or with one that uses distribute instead of setuptools as described by [Reinout van Rees](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/10/15/distribute-works-with-buildout.html).
4. `python bootstrap.py` (or `python bootstrap_dev.py` if you want to use distribute).
5. `./bin/buildout`

That's it. You should now have a new folder "my_new_site", which is your new django 1.1.1 project, and in ./bin you will find the `django`-script which replaces the manage.py on a normal installation.

What's the benefit? Let's say you want to use something like django-comment-spamfighter in your project. All you'd have to do is change your buildout.cfg to something like this:

```
[buildout]
parts=django

[django]
recipe=djangorecipe
version=1.1.1
project=my_new_site
settings=development
eggs=
    django-comments-spamfighter==0.4
```

Note that all I did was to add the last 2 lines which say, that the django-part should also have the django-comments-spamfighter package in version 0.4. The next time you run `./bin/buildout`, buildout will download that package and modify ./bin/django to add it to its PYTHONPATH.

djangorecipe is also suited for deploying your project with mod_wsgi. Just add the `wsgi=true` setting to the django-part of your buildout.cfg and a "django.wsgi" will appear in your ./bin folder :-)

And if you set the `test` option to a list of applications, the djangorecipe will create a nice wrapper for you that runs all the tests for the listed application in your project.

If you want to develop a single app in a standalone environment for debugging etc., Jakob Kaplan-Moss has a quite complete tutorial on [his blog](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/)

Answer (score 5):

Use reverse in your urlconf.

This is one of those tricks where I don't understand why it isn't the default.

Here's a link to where I picked it up:
http://andr.in/2009/11/21/calling-reverse-in-django/

Here's the code snippet:

> ```
> from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
> from django.utils.functional import lazy
> from django.http import HttpResponse
>
> reverse_lazy = lazy(reverse, str)
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
> url(r'^comehere/', lambda request: HttpResponse('Welcome!'), name='comehere'),
> url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to',
> {'url': reverse_lazy('comehere')}, name='root')
> )
> ```

Comment: What does that mean and why would I want to do it?

Comment: Reverse is like the URL tag, which "Returns an absolute URL (i.e., a URL without the domain name) matching a given view function and optional parameters." I avoid harding code absolute URLs. When I go to deploy on a web server, the app may not be the root mount point, so in the test server a URL like /app/url/ might work, but on the deploy server it might be /mountpoint/app/url.

Reverse works in views.py. But it doesn't work in urls.py. It gives the error: "The included urlconf foo.urls doesn’t have any patterns in it". This trick saves you from needing to wrap the URLconf in a view.

Comment: -1, this is a horrible hack to solve the root url problem. `PythonOption django.root` is the correct way. See the relevant documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modpython/#basic-configuration

Answer (score 5):

Automatically set 'DEBUG' attribute on production environment (settings.py)

```
import socket

if socket.gethostname() == 'productionserver.com':
    DEBUG = False
else:
    DEBUG = True
```

By: http://nicksergeant.com/2008/automatically-setting-debug-in-your-django-app-based-on-server-hostname/

Answer (score 4):

This is a really easy way to never have to import another one of your models again in your python shell.

First, install [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) (If you don't use IPython, what's wrong with you?).  Next, create a python script, ipythonrc.py, in your django project directory with the following code in it:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_models 
for m in get_models(): 
     globals()[m.__name__] = m 
#NOTE: if you have two models with the same name you'll only end up with one of them
```

Then, in your ~/.ipython/ipythonrc file, put the following code in the "Python files to load and execute" section:

```
execfile /path/to/project/ipythonrc.py
```

Now every time you start up IPython or run `./manage.py shell` you will have all your models already imported and ready to use.  No need to ever import another model again.

You can also put any other code you execute a lot in your ipythonrc.py file to save yourself time.

Comment: consider using "django command extensions" which which adds the ./manage.py shell_plus command which does this for you (several other cool stuff, too.)

Answer (score 4):

**Changing Django form field properties on init**

Sometimes it's useful to pass extra arguments to a Form class.

```
from django import forms
from mymodels import Group

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    group=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)
    email=forms.EmailField()
    some_choices=forms.ChoiceField()


    def __init__(self,my_var,*args,**kwrds):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwrds)
        self.fields['group'].queryset=Group.objects.filter(...)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['size']='50'
        self.fields['some_choices']=[[x,x] for x in list_of_stuff]
```

source: [Dzone snippets](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7936)

Comment: Brilliant! I've just been wrapping my Form classes in functions which doesn't seem as Pythonic as this.

Answer (score 2):

`django_extensions` from https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions is just great.

Few nice `./manage.py` commands:

- `shell_plus` - autoimports models from all INSTALLED_APPS
- `show_urls` - prints all urls defined in all apps in project
- `runscript` - runs any script in project context (you can use models and other Django-related modules)

Answer (score 2):

PyCharm and Wingware IDE is great tool if you have money to pay for the license.

Since I am a poor developer, I use [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) with [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [isapi-wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/isapi-wsgi/) and [django-pyodbc](http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/) to run Django on Windows using IIS and SQL Server!

Answer (score 1):

Create dynamic models for sets of legacy tables with the same structure:

```
class BaseStructure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class DynamicTable(models.Model):
    table_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def get_model(self):
        class Meta:
            managed=False
            table_name=self.table_name

        attrs = {}
        attrs['Meta'] = Meta

        # type(new_class_name, (base,classes), {extra: attributes})
        dynamic_class = type(self.table_name, (BaseStructure,), attrs) 
        return dynamic_class

customers = DynamicTable.objects.get(table_name='Customers').get_model()
me = customers.objects.get(name='Josh Smeaton')
me.address = 'Over the rainbow'
me.save()
```

This assumes that you have legacy tables with the same structure. Instead of creating a model to wrap each of the tables, you define one base model, and dynamically construct the class needed to interact with a specific table.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party. But Django Canvas has recently come out and it deserves a place here.

Don't start your project with `django-admin.py startproject`. Instead you can use something like [Django Canvas](http://djangocanvas.com) to help piece together a blank project with the modules you need.

You go to that site, tick some options and then download a blank project, so simple.

It has all the common things like South schema migrations and Command Extensions as well as a lot of other best practices mentioned here. Plus it has a great `start.sh/shart.bat` script that will install python, virtualenv, pip, django and whatever you need to start from a fresh copy of windows, osx or linux.

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronous tasks. Use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Read [Unbreaking Django](http://thebuild.com/presentations/unbreaking-django.pdf) if you haven't already. It contains *lots* of useful information regarding django pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

When passing variables from a view to a template the response dictionary can become tedious to type out. I find it nice to just pass all the local variables at once using `locals()` .

```
def show_thing(request, thing_id):
    thing = Thing.objects.get(pk=thing_id)
    return render_to_response('templates/things/show.html', locals())
```

(Not a hidden feature per se but nevertheless helpful when new to Python and or Django.)

Edit: Obviously it's better to be explicit than implicit but this approach can be helpful  during development.

Answer (score 0):

**dir() & raise ValueError()**

For debugging / exploring the state of things during development, I use the following trick:

```
...
  to_see = dir(inspect_this_thing)
  to_see2 = inspect_this_thing.some_attribute
  raise ValueError("Debugging")
...
```

This is especially helpful when you're working on parts of django that aren't particularly well documented (form.changed_fields is one I used this on recently).

**locals().**

Instead of writing out every variable for the template context, use the python builtin locals() command which creates a dictionary for you:

```
#This is tedious and not very DRY
return render_to_response('template.html', {"var1": var1, "var2":var2}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#95% of the time this works perfectly
return render_to_response('template.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#The other 4.99%
render_dict = locals()
render_dict['also_needs'] = "this value"
return render_to_response('template.html', render_dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

Django hasn't got app settings, so i made my own app_settings.py detection.
At the bottom of the settings.py i added this code:

```
import sys, os
# Append application settings without triggering the __init__.
for installed_app in INSTALLED_APPS:
    # Ignore django applications
    if not installed_app.startswith('django.'):
        # Find the app (and the settings file)
        for path in sys.path:
            path = os.path.join(path, installed_app, 'app_settings.py')
            if os.path.isfile(path):
                # Application settings found
                exec open(path).read()
```

It detects app_settings.py in all the INSTALLED_APPS. Instead of importing it, it will read the contents of the app_settings file and will execute it inline. If app_settings is imported directly all sort of Django import errors will be raised (because Django isn't initialized yet).

So my app/app_settings.py will look like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'app.middleware.FancyMiddleware',
)
```

Now the application only has to be added to the INSTALLED_APPS, instead of finding all application settings and add them to the settings.py (middleware, urls...)

Note: It would be better if Django had a hook to append extra settings, so application settings could be added on startup (or in runtime).