# Hidden Features of Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As a companion to [Hidden features of Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998/hidden-features-of-ruby).

Try to keep it to Rails since the other is a better place for Ruby-specific examples. One per post please.

Comment: How can there be an answer to this question? And I see you have marked one already.

Comment: That's true.  I just picked one since it was complaining at me about starting a bounty.  But you're right.  I took it off.

Comment: Why didn't this question took up like e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features ? Few votes, less answers ...

Answer (score 69):

To avoid duplicate form submissions, Rails has a nice option for submit tags:

```
submit_tag "Submit", :disable_with => "Saving..."
```

This adds behavior to the submit button to disable it once clicked, and to display "Saving..." instead of "Submit".

**Rails 4+**

```
 DEPRECATION WARNING: :disable_with option is deprecated and 
 will be removed from Rails 4.1. Use 'data: { disable_with: 'Text' }' instead.
```

Thus the above becomes:

```
submit_tag 'Submit', data: { disable_with: 'Text' }
```

Comment: One of my favourites, though I've found that it breaks some javascript validators somehow.

Comment: if you are using ajax for the submission, does it re-enable it?

Comment: If you're using the simple_form gem, I found [this tip](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11610795/418602) helpful for applying `disable_with` feature across the board.

Answer (score 22):

integer.ordinalize is one little method that I just stumbled upon not to long ago.

```
1.ordinalize = "1st"
3.ordinalize = "3rd"
```

Comment: Edge Rails (4.0.beta) has a related method 'ordinal' which will return only the suffix. 1.ordinal returns 'st', 34.ordinal returns 'th' and so on.

Answer (score 21):

I'm currently in love with `div_for` and `content_tag_for`

```
<% div_for(@comment) do %>
  <!-- code to display your comment -->
<% end %>
```

The above code renders this:

```
<div id="comment_123" class="comment">
  <!-- code to display your comment -->
</div>
```

Want the CSS class to be `comment other_class`?  No problem:

```
<% div_for(@comment, :class => 'other_class') do %>
  <!-- code to display your comment -->
<% end %>
```

Want a span and not a div?  No problem, `content_tag_for` to the rescue!

```
<% content_tag_for(:span, @comment) do %>
<% end %>

# Becomes...

<span id="comment_123" class="comment">
  <!-- code to display your comment -->
</span>
```

`content_tag_for` is also great if you want to prefix you `id`.  I use it for loading gifs.

```
<% content_tag_for(:span, @comment, 'loading') do %>
  <%= image_tag 'loading.gif' -%>
<% end %>

# Becomes...

<span id="loading_comment_123" class="comment">
  <img src="loading.gif" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 18):

To see a list of gems that are installed, you can run:

```
gem server
```

Then point your browser at:

```
http://localhost:8808
```

You get a nicely formatted list of your gems with links to rdoc, the web and any dependencies.  Much nicer than:

```
gem list
```

Comment: +1. Nice and neat! I used to play around with "gem search -l", this is definitely a better option.

Comment: This one is not Rails specific, is it? Just pointing out because you mentioned the other, Ruby-related thread, in your question.

Comment: This seems to be interesting....

Answer (score 16):

You can take advantage of the fact that Ruby class definitions are active and that Rails caches classes in the production environment, to ensure that constant data is only fetched from the database when your application starts up.

For example, for a model that represents countries you'd define a constant that performs a `Country.all` query when the class is loaded:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  COUNTRIES = self.all
  .
  .
  .
end
```

You can use this constant within a view template (perhaps within a select helper) by referring to `Country::COUNTRIES`. For example:

```
<%= select_tag(:country, options_for_select(Country::COUNTRIES)) %>
```

Answer (score 13):

in your environment.rb, you can define new date/time formats e.g.

```
[Time::DATE_FORMATS, Date::DATE_FORMATS].each do |obj|
  obj[:dots] = "%m.%d.%y"
end
```

so then in your views you can use:

```
Created: <%= @my_object.created_at.to_s(:dots) %>
```

which will print like:

```
Created: 06.21.09
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have a model with some class methods and some named scopes:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope 'nocturnal', :conditions => {'nocturnal' => true}
  named_scope 'carnivorous', :conditions => {'vegetarian' => true}

  def self.feed_all_with(food)
    self.all.each do |animal|
      animal.feed_with(food)
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can call the class methods through the named scope:

```
if night_time?
  Animal.nocturnal.carnivorous.feed_all_with(bacon)
end
```

Comment: Apparently your carnivores are vegetarian?

Answer (score 8):

Rails 2.3.x now allows you to do:

```
render @items
```

much simpler..

Comment: nice one!  we haven't been playing with 2.3 much - we're waiting for 3.0 at railsconf

Comment: To clarify: That will render a partial named 'items'?

Comment: @Matt, yes - I was following on from the previous example, which used a collection named @items. Obviously, the view needs to be correctly named for this magic to work.

Comment: With this syntax, doesn't rails look for the partial with the singularized name? e.g. "_item.html.erb"

Answer (score 7):

I'll start with one of my favorites.  When calling a partial with a collection, instead of looping through your collection and calling it for each item, you can use this:

```
render :partial => 'items', :collection => @items
```

This will call the partial once per item, and pass a local variable item each time.  You don't have to worry about nil checking @items either.

Comment: For above example, you have to partial named as model name of collection object. If you have partial with different name for example `foo` you can then use `render :partial => 'foo', :collection => @items, as: :item`. Now  you get object named `item` with in `foo` partial.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the behaviour of a model for your test suite. Say you have some after_save method defined and you do not want it to happen in your unit tests. This is how it works:

```
# models/person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  def after_save
    # do something useful
  end

end


# test/unit/person_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  class ::Person
    def after_save
      # do nothing
    end
  end

  test "something interesting" do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Funny feature is that array has special method for accessing its 42 element

```
a = []
a.forty_two
```

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Access.html#M003045

Comment: seems now this methods is not present in ruby 1.9.3

Comment: @RameshwarVyevhare, check Rails not Ruby

Comment: Ohh Sorry....i thought in ruby...!

Answer (score 4):

If you add routing for a resource:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :maps
end
```

And register additional mime-types:

```
Mime::Type.register 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml', :kml
```

You don't need a `respond_to` block in your controller to serve these additional types.  Instead, just create views for the specific types, for example `'show.kml.builder'` or `'index.kml.erb'`.  Rails will render these type-specific templates when requests for `'/maps.kml'` or `'/maps/1.kml'` are received, setting the response type appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = MyFormBuilderClass
```

Very useful when you're creating your own form builders. A much better alternative to manually passing :builder, either in your views or in your own `custom_form_for` helper.

Answer (score 1):

The returning block is a great way to return values:

```
def returns_a_hash(id)
  returning Hash.new do |result|
   result["id"] = id
  end
end
```

Will return a hash.  You can substitute any other types as well.

Comment: don't like it at all! it's not clear what it's returning at the end. it's been avoided in rails 3 refactoring.

Comment: that's too bad - i always thought it was pretty cool.

Comment: K combinator operator in ruby, that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Get everything printed with rake routes programmatically:

```
Rails.application.routes
```

Comment: Also, you can get all routes on browser on `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`