# Default disable_with for simple_form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want to change the default behavior of my submit button in simple_form so that I needn't explicitly specify :disable_with => true for all my forms. How can I make this particular change in the simple_form.rb?

Answer (score 6):

This is a little different in newer versions of Rails, as setting the property disable_with is deprecated. I wrote an article on this: http://www.railsonmaui.com/blog/2014/02/23/simple-form-and-disable-processing-by-default/

Here's the new code:

```
SimpleForm::FormBuilder.class_eval do
  def submit_with_override(field, options = {})
    data_disable_with = { disable_with: 'Processing...' }
    options[:data] = data_disable_with.merge(options[:data] || {})
    submit_without_override(field, options)
  end
  alias_method_chain :submit, :override
end
```

And thanks to @Appster for the idea!

Answer (score 3):

Adding this override to my simple_form.rb worked like a charm!

```
SimpleForm::FormBuilder.class_eval do
  def submit_with_override(field, options = {})
    submit_without_override(field, {:disable_with => 'saving...'}.merge(options))
  end
  alias_method_chain :submit, :override
end
```

Comment: For me, this works with some buttons and not others. Specifically, it works with `<%= f.button :submit %>` but not, for example, `<%= f.button :button %>` Could you explain what this is code is doing so I can work out how I might tweak my own settings?

Answer (score 2):

According to [ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.submit](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7a085dac2a2820856cbe6c2ca8c69779ac766a97/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1749), `f.button` accespts 1~2 parameters, so both of following codes should be worked.

- `f.submit "MyText", class: "my-btn"`
- `f.submit class: "my-btn"`

In my case, adding this codes to initialize file worked fine.

```rb
SimpleForm::FormBuilder.class_eval do
  def submit_with_override(value=nil, options={})
    value, options = nil, value if value.is_a?(Hash)
    data_disable_with = { disable_with: 'Processing...' }
    options[:data] = data_disable_with.merge(options[:data] || {})
    submit_without_override(value, options)
  end
  alias_method_chain :submit, :override
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't override any existing data- attributes on the submit button which is compatible with Rails 5.

```
module DisableDoubleClickOnSimpleForms
  def submit(field, options = {})
    if field.is_a?(Hash)
      field[:data] ||= {}
      field[:data][:disable_with] ||= field[:value] || 'Processing...'
    else
      options[:data] ||= {}
      options[:data][:disable_with] ||= options[:value] || 'Processing...'
    end
    super(field, options)
  end
end

SimpleForm::FormBuilder.prepend(DisableDoubleClickOnSimpleForms)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change it for a single item and not everything I thought I would share this.

I am using Rails v6.1.5 and Simple form and I ran into this Simple Form issue today.

I was trying to change the value of the submit button once pressed from

**'Change LOGO'**

to

**'Updating LOGO'**

I tried the normal way:

```
= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary', value: 'Change LOGO', id: 'submitLogo',
                  onclick: "logoSubmitButton(event)", disable_with: 'Updating LOGO'
```

It gave no error but it kept changing the button to **'Updating Company'** which is the name of the instance variable and the Model
**@company** and **Company** respectively.

This is what I had to use to make it work.  I didn't have to change anything on the simple_form.rb initializer file.

```
= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary', value: 'Change LOGO', id: 'submitLogo',
                  onclick: "logoSubmitButton(event)", data: {disable_with: 'Updating LOGO'}
```

This is the golden nugget that made it work:

```
data: {disable_with: 'Updating LOGO'}
```

I hope this helps someone else...

Scott