# Crossplatform deployment

Tags: django

I'm working with Django project on Linux and Windows. So I'm trying to config 'settings.py' to work on both platforms.

I can config the template dirs as:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    'c:/artefacts/workspace/BookMixToFb2/src/templates',
    '/home/demas/workspace/BookMixToFb2/src/templates'
)
```

and this will be work on linux and windows.

But when I setup a database connection I have only one possibility to set way to the database file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
         #'NAME': 'C:\\Users\\ademidov.GMCS\\workspace\\BookMixToFb2\\sqlite.db',                        # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'NAME': '/home/demas/workspace/BookMixToFb2/sqlite.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
```

Is there any way to set two different paths to database file and pass the current path as command line argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use this [tip: Use os.path.dirname() in settings.py to avoid hardcoded dirnames.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features/550644#550644)