# IOS SDK: first advice for beginners

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, memory-management

I too often answer the same kind of questions regarding basic topics like memory management, UITableView, Interface Orientation, MVC, etc...

I understand very well that everyone starting with that SDK is too exited about getting its hand on it, but a little reading would save them hours of debugging and the frustration that come along with the feeling that "We miss something here".

I'd like experienced users to share the few small articles, white papers, documentation, book chapters that helps other save their time and avoid frustration.

My first vote would be for:

- [IOS Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)
- [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Table View Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

And as a general recommendation, **read the overview section** that come along with the documentation for every class in the reference library, it contains most of what you need to know to avoid the big traps!

Comment: shouldn't this be a community wiki?

Comment: @vikingosengundo : Yes ! How can I do this ?

Comment: I made my answer a wiki and copied your links.

Comment: When u edit ur qusetion: is there a checkbox "community wiki" at the end of the form?

Comment: No.  That what I hope I would found but nothing ! Only my answers has this check !

Comment: hm, I never marked a question "wiki" either. But it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features/1407331#1407331

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72908/how-to-create-community-wiki-questions

Comment: I asked this question on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73324/flag-for-moderator-attention-when-question-might-be-community-wiki/73325#73325)

Answer (score 9):

## Good Resources

### Apple-provided documentation:

- [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/index.html)
- [Your First iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html)
- [Getting Started with iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163)
- [IOS Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)
- [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Table View Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

### iTunes U

- [iTunes U: Stanford — Developing Apps for iOS by Paul Hegarty](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=395605774)
- [iTunes U: Stanford — iPhone Application Development by Alan Cannistraro and Josh Shaffer](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225)
- [Apple's WWDC10 Session Videos](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092414566) <sub>(apple developer login required)</sub>

### YouTube

- [The New Boston](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xqn5IHbusA&list=SP640F44F1C97BA581)
- [Geeky Lemon Development](http://www.youtube.com/user/GeekyLemon/videos)

Comment: WWDC session videos are really helpful to getting guidance for new feature on the API.

Comment: I find WWDC videos very helpful but quite slow, you need at least 2-3 hours in advance before itunes shows them up.

Comment: @NiravBhatt: must be your connection. Here they load within minutes.

Comment: What I notice is itunes doesn't seem to buffer them, it just waits. I don't notice this problem with other networks like youtube,metacafe etc.

Comment: as I said: works fine here. you should talk to your ISP.