# railscasts.com like site for iOS 5 programming

Tags: ios, ios5

I learnt a great deal of ruby on rails from the video tutorial on the website www.railscasts.com. Is there a similar website for iOS/iOS 5 programming? Thanks.

Comment: resources, videos, tutorials: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539990/ios-sdk-first-advice-for-beginners/4540136#4540136

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following sites

[Stanford Videos](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522)

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/beginning-ios-development/

[WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/videos/)