# Expiring Data In Table View (Even After An App Is Closed And Restarted) (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, plist

I need help being pointed in the right direction (to the right documentation or tutorial) since I don't know exactly what this programming would be filed under.

Basically, I saw an app that had a section of 'Deals' on food and drinks at stores. You had to use the app to redeem the deal, but you could only use the deal once. It seemed that the table view of deals was being populated by a PList from a server (because it is constantly updated) BUT when you choose a deal and use it, it disappears from the table view (because you claimed it).

Now I was thinking it could be coding using an if else statement declaring integer values (and if they weren't equal to the integer, then the deal wouldn't display) but that can't be the case because if I close out the app and reopen it, the deal still isn't in the list. Am I right in assuming that somehow the PList or database is being updated by the user interaction? Are databases for each user being created when someone downloads the app (or starts it)?

I'm kinda in the dark about it and trying to figure out how they pull this off. I'm not sure if I'm way off base and there is some sort programming that I'm possibly not even aware of. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid, you have to work yourself through the primordial soup of cocoa-touch and objective-c. some useful resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539990/ios-sdk-first-advice-for-beginners/4540136#4540136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should investigate **NSFetchedResultsController** - it allows to perform a lot of pretty things with your data + database.
Check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) tutorial.

Also, take a look at the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Core data basics strongly required.

Comment: Great, this is a great place to start. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!