# Two UIScrollview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I was able to run one UIScrollview in my app,my goal is to run two UIScrollview in one view. How will I able to put two UIScrollview instances into my nib file and bind both of their datasources/delegates to the view controller as normal?

Comment: @vikingosegundo hi sir? do you need to see my whole code? I tried adding another UIView. then connecting it again with the same delegate and datasource, but it doesn't appear.

Comment: aroth gave you all the information, you need. if you can't handle it, you should start with some beginner courses. a collection of resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539990/ios-sdk-first-advice-for-beginners/4540136#4540136

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do that? What problems occured then? You just add them to you xib and everyting works. In your delegate calss you just inspect what exact `scrollview` did call this and do the things accordingly.

Comment: Nothing appears. Even my other UIScrollView was gone. Do I have to make another class(.m and .h file) to assign it with?

Comment: No,you can do it in one .m file.Just make it step by step.try to do it again, there should't be any tricky things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.  If you take a look at the [UIScrollViewDelegate reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) you will see that all of the delegate methods accept as a parameter the `UIScrollView` instance that triggered the call.  This is so that when multiple `UIScrollView` instances share a single delegate object (which is what you are trying to do), the delegate can still determine which `UIScrollView` has fired each event/delegate callback.