# Create inheritance graphs/trees for Django templates

Tags: python, django, templates, uml, class-hierarchy

Is there any tool out there that would take a directory with a Django application, scan it for templates and draw/print/list a hierarchy of inheritance between templates?

Seeing which blocks are being overridden at every level would be an especially helpful feature in such a tool.

Comment: I've asked a similar question, the short answer is no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954500/is-there-a-tool-for-django-project-structure-information-flow-visualization

Comment: Not at this moment, no. I've been working on something similar but due to work pressures I could never finish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but FWIW there is (or was) [django-template-graph](https://github.com/caktus/django-template-graph) that should work with Django 1.7.

It doesn't (yet) work with Django 1.8+ when the template logic changed a bit so it needs to be patched, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/caktus/django-template-graph/issues/34) for that and will probably release a fix soon.

Comment: Note that I'm not the owner of django-template-graph. I haven't gotten around to fix it yet, so there's no pull request yet.