# Loading django custom template tag at onece

Tags: python, django, templates, tags

I have my custom template tag. How to load it at once, without `{% load tag %}` in every template-file?

UPD:

As suggested by Yuji:

```
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('myapp.templatetags.mytagslib')
```

however, I don't use django, only templates - what should i write instead of `myapp.templatetags.mytagslib`?

UPD2: ok, tried `django.templatetags...`, works ;-)

Comment: I think you have to use that in every file.  I'm not aware of a way around that.  (EDIT: But now I am... see Yuji's answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

[Load a Django template tag library for all views by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default)

[Favorite Django Tips & Features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features)

I will remember this one, thanks :)