# Django project templates related css is not working in production

Tags: django, django-deployment

I got following settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'appname'), )
```

In my templates I got

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href"{% static 'appname/css/main.css' %}" />
```

1. My static folder includes default Django admin css and js like
   /static/css and its working fine.
2. My same static folder includes /static/appname/css/main.css

Still my css is not coming up. 
My templates are showing up but without css/js.
I got all my folders such as 'templates', static', 'static-files' under my project folder.

My default Django static files are showing after "coollectstatic" under static/admin. But I have no idea how to use "STATICFILES_DIRS" in production to show my project template related static files. 
I am deploying for production. Please advise.

Comment: you need to configure the web server to redirect static to that folder, and run collectstatic

Comment: share your directory structure.

Comment: As mentioned my Django default static files are showing up. But not my project static files.

Comment: I've added details about my directory structure above.

Comment: Do you have static folder at project level or app level? I mean your static folder is on this level "/project/static/" or on this /project/appname/static/ ?

Comment: Only project level. But I tried to add a sub folder with project name like /static/porjectfolder/ hoping that it will collect sub directory. It didn't worked. Do you want me to create my base.html under some app like /templates/appname/static? Currently its /project/static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that it needed settings in gunicorn from [What is the most common way to configure static files in debug and production for Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906197/what-is-the-most-common-way-to-configure-static-files-in-debug-and-production-fo) . The tutorial is not based on gunicorn but the link attached regarding gunicorn worked fine for me. I am thankful as you guys tried to help and stackoverflow just rocks.

Answer (score 0):

`collectstatic` copies everything *below* the paths in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. So since you are putting `appname` there your css file will end up at "/static/css/main.css". What you want to do is probably change the setting to:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Tried both ways...it collected static as I miss spelled the folder under static/appname. But later on it collected it but domain in production still says after inspecting element that: "Failed to load resources: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found) http://domain.com/static/css/main.css" and same for js files and others. HTML is coming fine though and css for Admin is also working.

Comment: I am setting up with Gunicorn and Nginx and every time I make changes I restart both services just to make sure that changes take affect. So the problem is in project based templates related css only. Admin css working just fine as my site set to Debug=False.

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings like this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'appname'), 
)
```

Now you can load your static files like this

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href"{% static 'appname/css/main.css' %}" />
```

Comment: It is collecting static and showing in folder. But not coming up live somehow. I did what your guys told me exactly.

Comment: Are you checking it on production server on local machine?

Comment: I am in production as mentioned in question.