# Which gives better performance-passing parsed URL as args alongwith request or parsing URL in view-Django

Tags: python, django, parsing, url, args

I have an Django application where the URL's to be handled shall have a specific pattern like /servername/alpha/beta/2/delta/10/pie/1
Now i will be be needing these parameters contained in the URL and will persist them to the database when a URL beginning from /servername/ is being called.
So i have 2 ways of doing it

1. Pass parameters along with request to the relevant view.In this case my regex would ensure that i have param1 through param7 having values alpha,beta,2,delta,10,pie and 1 respectively.
2. Pass only the request without passing the parameters.I will either parse using regex the request.path_info or split request.path_info on a "/" and obtain relevant entries

   Which of these two methods shall be preferred in order to have better performance in terms of CPU and memory or maybe other factors i am not aware of.
   I believe that one can compare the two using time functions but i believe it won't present an accurate picture.Theoretically which approach shall be preferred and why?

Comment: Firstly, you should be sure that you need this optization. Are you sure? Is it a bottleneck of your app? If not, no optimization needed, choose any option, first looks more pythonic and clear.

Comment: At this stage i may not need optimization,but just to know,if in future,i may want to make this application a little more fast.

Comment: it seems pretty unlikely that url parsing is going to be even close to the slowest part if your request cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option two is inherently slower as your view would need to do this parsing each time, whereas Django's standard URL parser works off of compiled regular expressions. (The urlpatterns in `urls.py` is compiled once on first run.)

However, the speed difference in either approach is pretty negligible. This will never be the bottleneck of your application; focus on things like your database and queries thereof and any I/O operations in your app (anything that writes or reads extensively from the hard drive). Those are where apps get slowed down. Otherwise, you're talking in terms of saving a millisecond here or there, which is fruitlessly pointless.

Comment: Thanks!I guess going through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features shall help me find tips to optimise my application.Also there's this video http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/django-deployment-workshop-3651591 from the Django founder which i guess shall be handy to others also and admin might wanna put this link in some thread