# Open file in Django app

Tags: python, django, file, directory

I want to open a file from a Django app using `open()`. The problem is that `open()` seems to use whatever directory from which I run the `runserver` command as the root.

E.g. if I run the server from a directory called foo like this

```
$pwd
/Users/foo
$python myapp/manage.py runserver
```

`open()` uses `foo` as the root directory.

If I do this instead

```
$cd myapp
$pwd
/Users/foo/myapp
$python manage.py runserver
```

`myapp` will be the root.

Let's say my folder structure looks like this

```
foo/myapp/anotherapp
```

I would like to be able to open a file located at `foo/myapp/anotherapp` from a script also located at `foo/myapp/anotherapp` simply by saying

```
file = open('./baz.txt')
```

Now, depending on where I run the server from, I have to say either

```
file = open('./myapp/anotherapp/baz.txt')
```

or

```
file = open('./anotherapp/baz.txt')
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The solution has been described in the [Favorite Django Tips&Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550632/favorite-django-tips-features) question. The solution is as follows:

```py
import os
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current directory
file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'baz.txt')
```

Which does exactly what you mentioned.

Ps. Please do not overwrite `file` variable, it is [one of the builtins](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file).

Comment: Thanks again. Obviously Python is not my normal weapon of choice.

Comment: This was just what I needed for my own issue. Thanks!

Comment: What if you need to go one step inner. i mean what if baz.txt file is inside some folder in module_dir lets say foo/baz.txt?

Comment: @user570826: Either try `file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'foo/baz.txt')` or `file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'foo', 'baz.txt')`.

Comment: can you tell my why this works .?  why must use module dir by os.path.dirname(__file__)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar case. From inside my *views.py* I needed to open a file sitting in a directory at the same level of my app:

```
-- myapp
 -- views.py     # Where I need to open the file
-- testdata
 -- test.txt     # File to be opened
```

To solve I used the **BASE_DIR** settings variable to reference the project path as follows

```
...
from django.conf import settings
...

file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'testdata/test.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer through another stack overflow question (yes, I did search before asking...)

I now do this

```
pwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file = open(pwd + '/baz.txt')
```

Comment: Just FYI: You can also do this: `import socket`, then you can use `socket.gethostname()` to determine hostname of the system you're on. Set up your path based on which hostname is returned.

Comment: @PaulHunter: Instead of `pwd + '/baz.txt'` you should use `os.path.join(pwd, 'baz.txt')`.