# copy directory name and placing it into a variable (python)

Tags: python, directory

I am new to python and I am struggling to accomplish a simple ask. I am trying to copy my current directory name and placing it into a variable. I dont need the contents of that directory, or the path to that directory. I just need the name of my current directory to be placed into a variable.

Thank you

Comment: This is kind of confusing are you trying to get the directory that the script is in or what  post your code with the question

Comment: Yes. The directory that my script is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For current working directory, use:

```
import os
cdir=os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]
print (cdir)
```

For the script directory, use:

```
import os
sdir=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).split(os.sep)[-1]
print (sdir)
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9711761/548696), you can achieve that this way:

```
import os
module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  # get current file's directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`os.getcwd`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd) along with [`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename).

```
os.getcwd()                   # => '/Users/jon'
os.path.basename(os.getcwd()) # => 'jon'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
x = cdir=os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]
print x
```

this assigns x the directory name and then prints it but you dont have to print it