# how to output a graph from csv using matplotlib and displaying it into browser using django?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

i wanted to create a django aplication which shows the graph using the data in the csv. I write a code in views file of the application repository. and also i placed the csv file along with views.py file. The codes are as follows

```
#from django.shortcuts import render
import sys
from sys import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as xy
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import Formatter
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
import csv

def graph():
    a=[]
    b=[]
    c=[]
    h=[]
    a1=[]
    b1=[]
    c1=[]
    j= open("Tier 1 Lake.csv")
    for row in csv.reader(j):
        a.append(row[8])
        b.append(row[28])
        c.append(row[2])
    for i,v in enumerate(a):
        if b[i]:
            a1.append(a[i])
            b1.append(b[i])
            c1.append(c[i])
    d=[item for item in range(len(c1)) if c1[item] == 'JOR-01-L']
    e=[a1[i] for i in d]
    f=[b1[i] for i in d]
    FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y'
    s =  sorted(zip(e,f), key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0],'%m/%d/%Y'))
    r= [x[1] for x in s]
    t= [x[0] for x in s]
    g= len(e)
    for k in range(0,g):
        h.append(k)
    fig, ax = xy.subplots()
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    xy.plot(h,r)
    xy.xticks(h,t)
    xy.plot(r, '-o', ms=10, lw=1, alpha=1, mfc='orange')
    xy.xlabel('Sample Dates')
    xy.ylabel('Air Temperature')
    xy.title('Tier 1 Lake Graph (JOR-01-L)')
    xy.grid(True)
    xy.show()

    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
    canvas.draw()
    graphIMG = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
    graphIMG.save(buffer,"PNG")
    xy.close()

    return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type="image/png")
```

Links and urls are functioning absolutely fine.
THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS " No such file or directory: 'Tier 1 Lake.csv'-- IO Error"

Comment: Have you read and tried this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711255/open-file-in-django-app ?

Comment: Where are you hung up? Reading the CSV? Making the figure? Saving the figure as an image? Displaying the image in Django? These are completely orthogonal issues this question should focus on exactly 1 of them.

Comment: I need to kno where to keep csv database and how to fetch the values from it. I am done with plotting graph and displaying its image into browser. And I am using sqlite database.