# How to automate Orca.exe "Transform -> View Patch"?

Tags: powershell, automation, wix, windows-installer, orca

I would like to automate MSI patch generation. Our build needs is the next `DiskId` and  `LastSequence` (or `SequenceStart` as input. They can be read from the table `Media` with the orca.exe tool and "Transform -> View Patch": [image: Orca showing DiskId and LsatSequence]

I found [this powershell](https://mickitblog.blogspot.com/2016/06/powershell-pulling-information-from-msp.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668122/how-to-extract-data-file-count-from-msi-file-table) on how to extract values from MSI/MSP files, however, it seems the `LastSequence` can only be obtained by opening MSI and MSP file together in orca. How can I read this value automatically (with Powershell preferably)?

Comment: I'm sure you can get the information through MSI API, as Orca propably uses MSI API too. My MSI API knowledge is somewhat rusty. Maybe it is as easy as adding the file count of the patch to the LastSequence number of the MSI.

Comment: From what I can see via orca, the msp does not allow for getting the file count either. Any suggestions where to read about that topic?

Comment: I tried `SELECT * FROM File`, but that only works for MSI files.

Comment: I don't have suggestions where to read about that topic. You could try to open the patch with [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/), a better alternative to Orca. Maybe it lets you figure out more information.