# How to include wxi file into wxs?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, merge-module

Following the [excellent suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-best-practices) I have moved some variables to **WXI file**. How do I include it in **WXS file**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for reference:

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm

Although this is about wix 2.0 and uses a file with extension .wxs - the game stays the same, as only the "include" element is required to exist in the file.

A good article how to use this can be found here:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/02/17/WiX-3-Tutorial-Understanding-main-WXS-and-WXI-file.aspx

Comment: Also, note that you have to **include in each .wxs file** where you want to use the variables. The only way to avoid this is to define vars at the project level: right-click the project > Properties > Build tab.

Answer (score 37):

use <?include ?> preprocessor tag, for example:

```
 <?include include.wxi ?>
```

Comment: It works only for 32bit installer. For 64bit this inclusion does not work. I get error: Schema validation failed with the following error at line 1, column 245: The element 'Wix' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'Bundle Product Module Patch Fragment PatchCreation'.

Comment: @jero2rome It is because you added `<?include ... ?>` at the top of the wsx file. wsi files containing `<Fragment>` elements must be added after the `<Product>` element