# MSI Reference Counting: Two products install the same MSIs

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3, merge-module

When products A and B each install several MSIs and some of the MSIs are the same, will uninstalling either A or B affect the other? Does install location matter?

Also, what happens when common MSI C's version is higher in Product B and B upgrades C on install? Now uninstalling B will remove the common MSI C which breaks Product A. How do you handle this gracefully without using the Permanent flag?

Comment: What do you mean by "product"? A WiX Bootstrapper (aka burn) installer?

Comment: The easy way to say it: **bundle files together that change together**. If there are too many dependencies and overlaps you need a better decomposing of the overall deployment structure. Shared files change together, product release files change together - with some managable exceptions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind with this question is whether the products in question are decomposed the way they should be.

As a **general rule** all MSI files think they own whatever they install, and they will uninstall everything attached to a component GUID inside the MSI on uninstall if the reference count (number of products using the component) is zero.

There are **some qualifications to this rule**:

- If the component is marked **permanent**  it is never uninstalled
- If the file / registry item has **no component GUID** at all, it is installed, never tracked by Windows Installer, and won't get uninstalled either
- Finally the **reference counting for MSI** allows the same component to be shared between several products and it will persist on disk during uninstall if it is registered in use by several other installer packages

The **mechanisms for creating shared components** between MSI packages are generally:

1. **Merge modules** allow you to install shared components that are reference counted and that will remain on disk after uninstall of a related product if there are other clients using the GUID on the system. A merge module is merged into other MSI packages at compile time. A form of **binary early binding** if you like. It can be merged into any package.
2. With the advent of **[Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060281/windows-installer-vs-wix/12101548#12101548)** (xml based installer source files), it is possible to include the same segment of files from several setups via an [**XML source include file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310832/how-to-include-wxi-file-into-wxs) instead of a merge module. This is vastly superior in my opinion due to the fact that Wix works better for source control ([see Wix link for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060281/windows-installer-vs-wix/12101548#12101548)). It is **crucially important** to realize that a "**Wix source include file**" has the exact same effect as a merge module - its components are reference counted properly for sharing between different installer packages, provided the GUIDs in the source file are hard coded (I recommend not to use auto-generated guids for this particular purpose). It is my personal opinion that you should use third party merge modules for generic runtime files, but **only** Wix includes for your own shared files. Merge modules are harder to manage than Wix includes imho.

**Updating and file replacement**:

- As to update scenarios the [MSI file replacement rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371221(v=vs.85).aspx) will take care of updating newer files, dependent upon the overall setting in the special Windows Installer property [REINSTALLMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx).
- In general higher version files overwrite lower version files. Non-versioned files are overwritten if they are unmodified. If they are modified the create and modified date stamps are different and the file is left alone.
- Keep in mind that the issue of **downgrading files** is actively discouraged by the overall MSI design. If you need to downgrade files (shared or not), there is something **deployment smelly** about your design.

At this point I would thoroughly read these answers:

- [Windows Installer and the creation of WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060281/windows-installer-vs-wix/12101548#12101548) - for a short Wix history and context
- [Change my component GUID in wix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405100/change-my-component-guid-in-wix/1422121#1422121) - for component reference counting
- [Wix installation, server, client or both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136446/wix-installation-server-client-or-both/25138758) - for client / server packaging
- [Wix to Install multiple Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542656/wix-to-install-multiple-applications/1546916#1546916) - for changing requirements and setup problems
- [WiX tricks and tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips) - for community Wix tips and tricks
- [How to include wxi file into wxs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310832/how-to-include-wxi-file-into-wxs) - for a simple idea of how to deal with Wix include files

Provided you use Wix, or you are willing to use Wix, I would think the best way to deal with your overlapping products would be to decompose your installer into **Wix segment source files** that you include as needed in your main installers. This will allow the uninstall of one product to leave in place any components used by other applications.

**With that being said, I do not like to cause too many overlapping dependencies in my installers** for the reasons listed in this article (also listed above): **[Wix to Install multiple Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542656/wix-to-install-multiple-applications/1546916#1546916)** .

For **stability** it is crucially important that **shared components** are **stable before being used by too many setups** as a bug fix as a general rule will require the recompilation of all setups the shared component is compiled or merged into. **The easy way to say it: bundle files together that change together**.

To counteract this need for massive recompilation, you can chose to deliver a stand-alone supporting setup consisting of some of the shared components. One, or a couple of such "**shared components setups**" that are likely to contain Wix includes that change together on a similar, **slow release schedule**, and then **separate setups for each product** should be able to account for any deployment need whilst maintaining a **balance between maintainability and flexibility**.

The product setup should then be the one that gets recompiled often, and the shared modules setups should be designed for minimal recompilation. Then wait for changing requirements :-).

To me it is all about **cohesion** and **coupling**, and the difficulty of balancing sales, marketing and technical needs.

Comment: I've been trying for most of the day to get this to work via XML source include file. I've got my AppPool defined in an include file with a predefined GUID id in a setup library. It's referenced by two setup projects that create simple websites. It installs the sites and AppPool is shared but when I uninstall either of them the AppPool is removed and the other website is broken. What am I doing wrong? Could you provide a basic example?

Comment: You need to hard code the guid for it to remain stable between releases and allow reference counting to work as designed. Check that you don't auto-generate the guids for the components in question.

Comment: When I said 'predefined GUID id in a setup library', I meant that I have hard coded the guid in the shared component. I've also added the 'Shared' attribute with value 'yes'. But still same behaviour.

Comment: Finally got it working after I removed the keypath attribute from the shared component and and Directory="TARGETDIR" instead.

Answer (score 4):

If Product A and Product B has a MSI C in common then
If Product A is installed, also MSI C is installed, now when Product B is installed MSI C will not be installed since its already available in the system (if Product B is WiX Burn based, it registers a dependency). In case of uninstallation reference counting is automatically handled if Product A and Product B is WiX Burn based installer or any other Bootstrapper which supports reference counting else MSI C is removed along with Product B.

Answer (score 1):

even I was looking for the answer of the above question, but in Wix v3.7 and higher, the MSI packages are automatically reference counted by the Burn engine. I have tested this, and works perfect.
The same can be checked in [Rob's blog](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/12/24/wix-v3.7-released/)

Comment: Considering the time difference from when the question was asked and your answer, you might consider leaving it as a comment to the accepted answer.