# WIX Win64="no" no effect

Tags: wix

I have following component in installer

```
  <Component Id="my.dll" Guid="*" Win64="no">
    <File Id="my.dll" Name="my.dll" KeyPath="yes" ReadOnly="yes" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.TargetDir)/my.dll" />
  </Component>
```

In visual studio configuration manager for solution platform x64 the installer project is set to x64.

When building x64, the build is still failing on this part, looking for `my.dll` although `Win64` is set to "`no`".

In the wixproj I have manually added by copying the x86 section:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64' ">
  <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>Debug</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Did same for `'Release|x64'`. and also tried removing following:

```
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
```

and also changing the `x86` to `x64` but this did not help.

Why is `x64` build still regarding this line although `Win64="no"`?

Comment: If you want to exclude authoring, use the preprocessor as @SteinÅsmul suggests. `Win64` controls the component attributes, not whether it's included.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Reference***: [Using Project References and Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html).

---

***TargetPath***: Maybe try to use **`$(var.ProjectName.TargetPath)`** instead of **`$(var.TargetDir)/my.dll`**. I think that is what is wrong. The TargetPath will be the whole path with file name for what you build. See the above "**Reference**" link for all these parameters (preprocessor variables).

---

***Extra Notes***: A couple of further things:

- Notice the **ProjectName** section: if your **Visual Studio project** is called **`MyLittleProject`**, then you should add: **`$(var.MyLittleProject.TargetPath)`**.
- The **`Win64="no"`** attribute for the Component element in WiX files affects where the file is installed on the target system where end-user installation happens, not where the Visual Studio build files are located on disk after successful build:

  - **`Program Files (x86)`** (32-bit) or **`Program Files`** (64-bit)
  - **`Windows`** (64-bit) or **`SysWOW64`** (32-bit, yes amazingly)

---

***Quick Sample***: This is from memory and probably not very good, but here is a sample of Preprocessor variables in action ([got this long answer on such constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449985/wix-installer-setting-component-condition-property-when-doing-a-msiexec-admin/49501700#49501700)):

```
<?if $(var.MyProjectName.Platform) = "x64" ?>      
  <Component>
     <File Source="C:\Test\Test1.exe" />
  </Component>
<?endif?>

<?if $(var.MyProjectName.Platform) = "Win32" ?>
  <Component>
     <File Source="C:\Test\Test2.exe" />
  </Component>
<?endif?>

<Component>
   <File Source="$(var.MyProjectName.TargetPath)" />
</Component>
```

Make sure the configuration is set to rebuild all projects including your WiX project. There could be unexpected exclusions. Notice how platform might say **`Win32`** versus **`x64`** for platforms (instead of the perhaps expected **`x86`**) - common errors. **`Inspect the compiled MSI`**. Also be sure to set a proper project build order (manipulate project dependencies).

---

***sys.BUILDARCH***: There is also the **`sys.BUILDARCH`** built-in variable, which has me a little confused to be honest. I have not used it. Search for it here: [Preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html). And [github](https://github.com/ksmyth/UDM/blob/3b2e5d46169f954c53ef26e79cf833f9e21e8a56/WiX/Udm_bin/Udm_bin.wxs).

Comment: So can I control which files are included per platform (e.g `x64`) & which are ignored?

Comment: Might be a smarter way, but there are always [Preprocessor variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) that you can use. Will update the answer with a quick hint. And [a generic hint on how to search github.com](https://github.com/search?l=XML&q=%3C%3Fif+%24%28var.+Platform+Wix&type=Code) for clues (must be logged into github.com to work).