# WiX overwrites config files during setup. How can I avoid this?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, configuration-files

I'm using WiX to create a windows installer. Unfortunately my installer overwrites a config file on every update. 
What I really want is, that the installer only creates the file if it is not found.

Thanks and regards,
  forki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sure someone will come up with a proper answer, but as a backup:

You could have the installer create a default configuration file, and then have your application copy the default file to the normal configuration file, if the normal configuration file is not present. This also provides an easy way to reset the application to factory default (just delete the configuration file).

Comment: Nice idea. But this doesn't work in my scenario - I can't change the app code.

Comment: It seems you accepted the wrong answer, man :) Dave Andersen below proposed a good workaround for your case.

Answer (score 38):

The `Component @NeverOverwrite="yes"` attribute might be the solution to this problem.

From the WiX help documentation:

> If this attribute is set to 'yes', the installer does not install or reinstall the component if a key path file or a key path registry entry for the component already exists. The application does register itself as a client of the component. Use this flag only for components that are being registered by the Registry table. Do not use this flag for components registered by the AppId, Class, Extension, ProgId, MIME, and Verb tables.

[Component Element Documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html)

Comment: Well, this seems to be a solution to the problem above, assuming the application can't be changed, just installer...

Comment: I don't know how heavy weight making the config file into it's own component, or whether the Registry table restriction matters.

Comment: The best practice is making every file it's own component. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602831/wix-one-file-per-component-or-several-files-per-component

Comment: @Simon Is your config file the keypath of its own component? Does it have a stable guid?

Comment: @Dave Andersen: Yes, my config file has the attribute  `KeyPath="yes"` and the parent Component element has a GUID. After an installation, the config file exists in the target folder. When I make an Update, the config file is the only file, that does not exist any more in the folder.

Comment: @Dave Andersen: In addition, I use heat.exe to harvest some files into the same folder. But not the config file itself will be harvested. Perhaps are there any relations?

Comment: @Simon, I don't know what else might be causing it. The next thing I would look at is the installer log for more clues. You could test for heat interactions by removing those components and testing that way too.

Comment: @Dave Andersen: I belive, the file will be deleted by InstallExecuteSequence > RemoveExistingProducts which is an compulsory element. I am wondering, about the 22 upvotes, because it obviously does not work.

Comment: @Simon, if you also need the file to remain during uninstall, you need to add the Permanent="Yes" attribute to your component. The 'NeverOverwrite' attribute only controls deployment of the component.
Another alternative would be to change your install sequence so that RemoveExistingProducts occurs after the component has been laid down. If you do that, it won't be removed because the reference count will never drop to zero during the upgrade.

Comment: Didn't work for repair.  Repair replaced the file with the vanilla one from the install.

      <Component Id="appsettings.Production.json" Guid="{XXXXXXXX-2178-41D8-A882-DB2BA217C15F}" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes" >
        <File Id="appsettings.Production.json.file" KeyPath="yes" Name="appsettings.json" Source="$(var.RELEASEBINARIES)\appsettings.Production.json" />
      </Component>

Answer (score 9):

`Component/@NeverOverwrite="yes"` will do this. Just remember to set `File/@KeyPath="yes"` on one or more of the files so it can detect whether it is already present.

If you're using heat.exe to harvest your file list automatically, you can use the following XSLT stylesheet to set this attribute on each Component containing a config file (and set each config File element as a key path).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl wix">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='Component']">
    <wix:Component Id="{@Id}" Directory="{@Directory}" Guid="{@Guid}">
      <xsl:if test="contains(*[local-name()='File']/@Source, '.config')">
        <xsl:attribute name="NeverOverwrite">yes</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </wix:Component>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@KeyPath">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(parent::node()/@Source, '.config')">
        <xsl:attribute name="KeyPath">
          <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note: the XML namespace handling can probably be cleaned up, but it works.)

Answer (score 5):

This really is an application bug, not a setup issue.

You shouldn't be "installing" data that is later editable by the user, Windows Installer records the size, modification date and hash value of files installed. That way if the file is later discovered to be "corrupt" it can be repaired.

We install a default config file that is copied to the user config when none is found, that way Windows Installer never even knows about the user editable config and so doesn't do any replacement.

Comment: As I've written above - unfortunately I can't fix the app.

Comment: What about configuration files that are configured on install.  For example, the app.config or web.config that has an install specific connection string.  What if this connection string needs to change after installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default behavior with [REINSTALLMODE property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371182(VS.85).aspx). It defaults to "Reinstall if the file is missing or is an older version", which is logically correct, as for me. But you can experiment with other values to find the behavior you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: REINSTALLMODE seems to be a global property. I only want to save one file.