# How to keep a configuration file when on upgrade but remove it on uninstall?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, wix3.8

I want to keep a config file when **on upgrading** but remove it **on uninstalling**.

```
<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="dir_99306542_9959_46A2_9928_91FA5A0112C0" Name="ProofpointPlugin">          
          <Component Id="comp_22FC069D_8417_4504_9F0F_4F01DD04C6C8" Guid="E0CC1916-F33F-48DC-8677-5FF077722114">
            <RemoveFile Id="remove_config_file" Name="config.json" On="uninstall"/>
            <Condition>(REMOVE=ALL) AND (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE)</Condition>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
```

And I have this to facilitate upgrades

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallInitialize'></RemoveExistingProducts>
```

Comment: Too busy, but I'll try to lob you some links instead: [**1: preserve config**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53586960/129130) and [**2: settings management**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48196886/129130). Plenty of further links in those main links. And finally [**do read this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49142733/129130) from MSI Expert Chris Painter.

Comment: [One more link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651809/129130). Some things you should know about file settings preservation, file overwrite and file reversion (uninstall and reinstall of file rather than overwriting).

Comment: On a side note, a `Component` condition will only be evaluated at installation time. It can't be used to conditionalize the removal of a file. You are effectively saying "Install this component, which is used for removing this file, only during uninstall". Well, you can't install anything during uninstall, which is the reason this doesn't work.