# Wix Toolset MajorUpgrade- merge files

Tags: wix

I would like to make a major upgrade and merge two config files(keep config changes from one file and get new configs from another - can be done with some script). Is it possible?

Comment: There are many [application settings management "strategies"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48196886/129130). IMHO this kind of task is best done during [application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48697347/129130).  The use of [template settings files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49142733/129130) that you keep read-only and then duplicate to create actual settings files that are then maintained by the application itself seems effective. The application launch is easy to debug and is "same source" as the rest of your code.

Comment: I wouldn't try to do merging during the setup, unless it is trivial. Major upgrades also have a tendency to revert settings if you don't watch out. This is because a major upgrade is an uninstall and a reinstall in sequence and your settings file might get removed and then re-installed making it look like it has been overwritten. Some further information: [settings preservation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375540/129130) and [settings preservation shorter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53586960/129130).