# Wix: Why the wix compiler accepts that a component contains multiple file?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I learned why it is very bad practice to include multiple files in a msi component. A msi component should contain only 1 file. Good references can be found here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/01/587990.aspx

http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2011/06/17/145898.aspx

[Wix: one file per component or several files per component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602831/wix-one-file-per-component-or-several-files-per-component)

My question is: since this one file per component rule is so important, why does the wix compiler accepts multiple file per component ?

Comment: Sort (partial) answer: WiX makes it easier to build Windows Installer packages. It couldn't do that if it made legal things impossible.

Comment: If anyone cared about this enough they could build themselves an ICE validation test and include it in the WiX build so it could cause an error. May already have been done for all I know.