# How does this left hand side assignment for a function call work in JScript?

Tags: javascript, jscript, advanced-installer

I was looking for a way to log down messages the installer log using JScript and stumbled upon this answer:

[How to debug an MSI Custom Action that is implemented in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785013/how-to-debug-an-msi-custom-action-that-is-implemented-in-javascript/1786688#1786688)

It works great. However there is something intriguing in the code that I haven't been able to figure out. In this method:

```
// spool an informational message into the MSI log, if it is enabled. 
function LogMessage(msg) {
    var record = Session.Installer.CreateRecord(0);
    record.StringData(0) = "CustomAction:: " + msg;
    Session.Message(MsgKind.Log, record);
}
```

How does the line `record.StringData(0) = "CustomAction:: " + msg;` work, from a syntax/semantic perspective? It looks to me this is trying to assign a value to the return value of a function call, which should be illegal or a no-op at best? Yet it works, and the message is printed out in the log.

What am I missing?

Comment: @JavaScript That isn't true for JavaScript, where the above would fail anyway; in JScript, however, Microsoft has created some 'special behaviour', that allows this on some special objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **JScript** way to access lists and not an actual function. Therefore it does not throw an `Invalid left-hand side in assignment`.

[StringData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/record-stringdata#property-value) is a list of values. What you are actually setting is the value of the `0` index. It is like setting the value to an array using `arr[0] = 'xyz'`. In your example you could also omit it:

```
record.StringData = "CustomAction:: " + msg;
```

### Syntax

```
propVal = Record.StringData
Record.StringData = propVal
```

### Property value

Required field number of the value within the record, 1-based.

### Remarks

The returned value of a nonexistent field is an empty string. To set a record string field to null, use either an empty variant or an empty string. Attempting to store a value in a nonexistent field causes an error.

Source: [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135203/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-jscript/135256#135256)

Comment: It's strange, apart from that answer from Patrick I haven't seen any mention of `()` being used as the index operator anywhere. Seems like a very obscure feature/syntax

Comment: @Chin: It is the only reference I found myself as well. I remember it pretty common in *ASP*, *VB* and *VB.Net*. There is usually is a *shorthand* for `x.item()`, yet I could not find any actual origin or implementation reference.