# WIX: How can I register a new ISAPI Extension or Script Map on an existing Web App or Site?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, isapi

I've seen the [WebApplicationExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_webapplicationextension.htm) element, but because it must be a child of [WebApplication](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_webapplication.htm), it appears to require the creation of a new WebApplication. I don't want that.

I want to create the extension (or script map) on an existing website.  On uninstall, the website should remain but the extension (script map entry) should be  removed.

Anyone know how to do this in WIX?

---

If I get no good answers, I guess I will have to do it within script before InstallFinalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to do this in WIX, so I resorted to a custom action.  I had been writing all my [custom actions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-best-practices/1801532#1801532).  I find Javascript to be easy to use and robust for that purpose, [despite what others have said](http://blogs.msdn.com/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx).

But I could not find a way to  add a scriptmap from Javascript, because the IIS metabase update requires the use of a VBArray datatype, which is supported in VBScript, but not in Javascript.  Whoops.

So, here is the code, in VBScript.

```
Function AddExtension_CA()

    VBSLogMessage("AddExtension_CA() ENTRY")
    Dim iis
    Set iis = GetObject("winmgmts://localhost/root/MicrosoftIISv2")

    dim siteName
    siteName = Session.Property("WEBSITE_NAME")

    VBSLogMessage "website name(" & siteName & ")"

    If (siteName <> "") Then
        Dim idir, dll
        idir = Session.Property("INSTALLDIR")
        dll = idir & "\MyIsapiExtension.dll"

        Dim query
        If (siteName <> "W3SVC") Then
            query = "SELECT * FROM IIsWebServerSetting WHERE Name = '" & siteName & "'"
        Else
            query = "SELECT * FROM IIsWebServiceSetting"
        End If

        Set results = iis.ExecQuery(query)
        Dim newMaps()   '' dynamically-sized Array

        '' two passes
        For t = 0 to 1
            Dim c
            c=0
            For Each item in results
                '' in pass 1, count them. 
                '' in pass 2, copy them.
                For i = 0 to Ubound(item.ScriptMaps)
                    If UCase(item.ScriptMaps(i).Extensions) <> ".IIRF" Then
                        If t = 1 Then
                            Set newMaps(c) = item.ScriptMaps(i)
                        End if
                        c = c+1
                    End If
                Next

                If t = 0 Then
                    ReDim Preserve newMaps(c)
                Else
                    VBSLogMessage("setting new filter")

                    Set newMaps(c) = iis.get("ScriptMap").SpawnInstance_()
                    newMaps(c).Extensions = ".iirf"
                    newMaps(c).ScriptProcessor= dll
                    newMaps(c).Flags = "1"
                    newMaps(c).IncludedVerbs = "GET,POST"
                    item.ScriptMaps = newMaps
                    item.Put_()
                End If
            Next
        Next

        VBSLogMessage("Allowing the DLL as an Extension")

        dim IIsWebServiceObj
        Set IIsWebServiceObj = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC")
        IIsWebServiceObj.AddExtensionFile dll, True, "GroupId", True, "Description of the Extension"
        Set IIsWebServiceObj = Nothing

    End If

    Set iis = Nothing

    VBSLogMessage("AddExtension_CA() EXIT")

    AddExtension_CA = 1   ' MsiActionStatus.Ok

End Function
```

Here's the WIX code:

```
<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="CA.AddExtension"
              BinaryKey="B.VBScript"
              VBScriptCall="AddExtension_CA"
              Execute="immediate"
              Return="check" />

    ....
```

See also:
[AddExtensionFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525260(VS.90).aspx).