# How do I check whether Adobe Acrobat is installed using WiX?

Tags: wix, acrobat

The whole question is pretty much in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acrobat Reader, Pro, Standard, 3D, etc? What version? Do you need Acrobat specifically? A PDF editor? A PDF viewer?

If you're not picky and are just looking for Acrobat Reader/Pro/Std, I'd start with the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AcroExch.Document` registry key.

If you're only concerned with a PDF application in general (Adobe, Foxit, Nitro PDF, etc, etc) then start with the `HKCR\.pdf` registry key.

Answer (score 0):

[WiX tricks and tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-best-practices/615470#615470) i think the problem turns to find the registry key for Acrobat.