# vs2010 Extensibility Tips and Tricks

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Diving into vs2010 Extensibility and I gotta say the subject seems to be as wide as it is deep. Anyone have tips, tricks or hacks to leverage jumping into this somewhat intimidatingly huge niche of visual studio?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Well as of right now any area of expertise on the subject would be helpful. But I suppose the same can be said in any number of languages\technologies. I was kinda hoping for this question to model somewhat after this one -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips

Comment: But in particular any intro level stuff would be helpful. Anything that would lower the bar to entry a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote 9 hours of Visual Studio Extensibility material for Pluralsight ([part 1](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/Course/Toc.aspx?n=vs2010-vsx), [part 2](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/Course/Toc.aspx?n=vs2010-vsx-code)). If you're an MSDN subscriber you can get a [one-month free subscription](https://www.pluralsight-training.net/offers/default.aspx?cc=MSDN) which should give you more than enough time to get through both courses. I also put together some 2008 and 2010 talks on VSX topics and both the slides and demos (along with videos) are on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSExtensionsIntroduction.aspx).

Comment: Sounds like a good way to spend my evening. Thx for the resources

Answer (score 1):

I'll be first then....

Saving the following text as a registry and appending it(open it with regedit) allows for easier identifying of a particular menu item or command and allows you to build on existing but hard to find UI elements... 

`Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\General]
"EnableVSIPLogging"=dword:00000001`

I found this useful tidbit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dr._ex/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1)

With [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223132939/http://mme.codeplex.com/) you can add Context Menus into you vs2010 IDE (New version is using MEF to some extent but there are older versions just using MAF). So much easier then MAF!!!

[VSPackage Builder:](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412112010/http://www.devx.com:80/VS_2010/Article/45656/0/page/1) Yet another awesome way to design Visual Studio Packages without having to rummage through the innards of a vs extension to design one.