# hide textboxes on checkbox checked in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is it possible to hide textboxes on checkbox checked in WiX?

Comment: I don't really understand what you need, but you can hide and show controls dynamically by using control conditions: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_condition.htm

Comment: Seems to be a special case of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241863/wix-interactions-with-conditions-properties-custom-actions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, the first comment helped me. It is done like this:

```
<Control Id="LoginTextBox" Type="Edit" Text="CM2" Height="17" Width="200" X="150" Y="198" Property="Login">
    <Condition Action="hide" >CreateDBUsers&lt;&gt;1</Condition>
    <Condition Action="show" >CreateDBUsers=1</Condition>
</Control>
```

Comment: But note that it won't happen dynamically. I mean, if you change the checkbox state, the edit boxes on the same dialog won't hide, even if the condition is appropriate, until you refresh the dialog (next/back)

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko: It won't? I thought most updates of this nature work fine. Those that don't: ones performed behind the UI's back (e.g. with MsiSetProperty), and ones that change properties associated with Edit controls whose text has already been changed by the user. Ones that do: enable/disable (such as in response to a radio button on a license dialog). Isn't hide/show in response to a checkbox like the latter?

Comment: Actually, they will hide dynamically, I've already tested it.

Answer (score 2):

*This is a very old question*, and the answer is: Yes it is possible.

I finally get how this works based on [this blog post](https://madtechnology.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/wix-enable-disable-controls-based-on-user-selection/) and [Bogdan Verbenets's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5510830/5948846). To elaborate already chosen answer, this snippet based on his answer might help you understand more:

```
<Control Id="AnyCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" Height="17" Width="10" X="150" Y="180" Property="CreateDBUsers" CheckBoxValue="1" />

<Control Id="LoginTextBox" Type="Edit" Text="CM2" Height="17" Width="200" X="150" Y="198" Property="Login">
  <Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[CreateDBUsers<>"1"]]></Condition>
  <Condition Action="show">CreateDBUsers="1"</Condition>
</Control>
```

Which the above code ***work the same*** as below:

```
<Control Id="AnyCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" Height="17" Width="10" X="150" Y="180" Property="CreateDBUsers" CheckBoxValue="0" />

<Control Id="LoginTextBox" Type="Edit" Text="CM2" Height="17" Width="200" X="150" Y="198" Property="Login">
  <Condition Action="hide"><![CDATA[CreateDBUsers<>"0"]]></Condition>
  <Condition Action="show">CreateDBUsers="0"</Condition>
</Control>
```

Please pay attention to `CheckBoxValue` which its value determine what you going to write in the condition text.

Note:

- It better to use `<![CDATA[ write_something_here ]]>` when you need to write conditional involving `<` (less than equal) or `>` (greater than equal).
- It might more proper to use string (`"1"`, `"0"`) in condition text since `CheckBoxValue` actually use string data type, you can check at [official documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/control.html). Although this is not mandatory.

*Check box is definitely quite a something different in WiX.*