# Get WiX property value from output of command?

Tags: wix, votive

Is there a way to execute a command (in PoSh, ideally) and assign the output to the value of a property in WiX?  So far, all I have seen is custom actions that will run a command, but not capture output or set a property's value.

Answer (score 1):

Custom actions can access the Wix Session and set a property on the session that can be read out later.

This is C# code but it would be similar in PS

```
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult myaction(Session session)
        {
            session["myvariable"] = "myvalue";
        }
```

After the action has been executed you can access it in the UI as if it where a normal property. Be aware though that if you are planning on changing the UI to respond to this you will need to use a hack to make the wix UI realise that the value has changed...see my answer in this SO question [Wix Interactions with Conditions, Properties & Custom Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241863/wix-interactions-with-conditions-properties-custom-actions/6433364#6433364)