# Custom error message using WiX setup

Tags: wix, wix3.5

Using a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) setup, how do I show a custom error message dialog where it shows all the installation checked processes as tick marks and the failed check processes as close marks?

[image: Sample of a custom error message using a WiX setup]

And if any file checking conditions are not met. That is, if any of the installations shows a close mark then how do I force the user to stop the installation setup process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using properties. Use the `Bitmap` control to set the icon.

```
   <Binary Id="RightClick" SourceFile="Resources\Right.jpg" />
   <Binary Id="WrongClick" SourceFile="Resources\Wrong.jpg" />
```

Use `SetProperty` or `CustomAction` to set the property value based on a condition and pass the value to the `Bitmap` control.

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />
<Property Id="NETFramework_Icon" Value="WrongClick" />
<SetProperty Id="NETFramework_Icon" Value="RightClick" After="AppSearch">NETFRAMEWORK40FULL</SetProperty>
```

In dialog,

```
<Control Type="Bitmap" Id="NETFramewor40ico" Width="20" Height="20" X="240" Y="70" Text="[NETFramework_Icon]" />
```

Regarding the second query, disable the next button if any prerequisites are not installed or throw a custom error for silent installation.

Comment: Can you please help me how to do change the image when i place a new button called refresh, what it will do is just calling my custom action and should change the images based on the conditons.I done this but what is happening is image is not changing if i am in the same window but if i go back and come to this screen again this is working.How can i do this in the same window itself.?

Comment: Try this stack overflow answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241863/wix-interactions-with-conditions-properties-custom-actions