# A tip information for text input in Installer using Wix

Tags: wix, dialog

I'm trying to program an Installation dialog.

What I've done is using a custom action, and when user click next on this dialog , installer will check the input and pop some alert about the information.

But my boss wants that the tip will reveal automatically at the right of the input text, so when the user finish one text and navigate to the next text, a tip will reveal if the input is not correct.

Seems updating a dialog is impossible, at least is there a way to reveal the tip on the dialog (not pop an alert) when user click next?

Comment: It's impossible with Windows Installer UI - no event is fired on leaving the edit area. You'll have to develop a custom UI if that's a must requirement.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Hi, then is it possible to reveal the tip when user click the next button?

Comment: Yes, but it also requires to apply a certain trick. Take a look at this answer and the referenced article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241863/wix-interactions-with-conditions-properties-custom-actions/4249826#4249826