# Wix: Define a variable according to Windows OS version: x86/x64

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a Wix xml for creating a msi setup.
I want a curtain component to be installed from a location based on the current Windows version - x86 or x64, and not based on the current `$(var.Platform)`, i.e. setup configuration.

How Can I do it? 
The best way I can think about is defining a variable, based on the Windows version:

```
  <?if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE~="amd64" OR %PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432~="amd64"?>
  <?define InstallationFolder = "x86" ?>
  <?else ?>
  <?define InstallationFolder = "x64" ?>
  <?endif ?>
```

And using it by the source path for the required component files.

The issue is that the boolean expression above has problems and doesn't detect the OS, it detects the proccess.
I though about using the `VersionNT64`, but I didn't see a way of how to use it in the `<?if>` boolean expression.

Comment: This appears to be a build issue, yes? If so VersionNT64 is irrelevant because it's a Windows Installer install-time property.  For builds it looks like you need var.Platform as in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/577793#577793  and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231950/using-wix-to-create-32bit-and-64bit-installers-from-one-wxs-file

Answer (score 0):

How about using a C# custom action to detect the 64 or 32 bit and just override the value from there?

Writing custom action:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html

[How to pass parameters to the custom action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101579/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-custom-action)