# platform independent registration of IIS with ASP in wix installer

Tags: asp.net, iis, wix, x86-64

I made a wix installer which successfully enables the IIS with asp by running the command Aspnet_regiis.exe on 64 bit system. However, this command has different path in .net framework folder depending on 32 bit or 64 bit system according to this link[IIS registration with ASP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.90).aspx)

on 32 bit system

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

and on 64 bit system

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

I need to extend my installer to cover both 32 bit and 64 bit platforms. I tried to this answer [answer on platform independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231950/using-wix-to-create-32bit-and-64bit-installers-from-one-wxs-file) by defining a preprocess variable based on the platform as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
      <?define IISRegCommand = "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i" ?>      
    <?else ?>
      <?define IISRegCommand = "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i" ?>
    <?endif ?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="IISRegistration" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Eurotherm By Schneider-Electric" UpgradeCode="4bfb41e4-5701-4a47-9c4c-cdb657ab7a62">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="IISRegistration" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>

        <CustomAction Id="IISRegistration" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" 
          ExeCommand="$(var.IISRegCommand)"
          Return="check"/>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="IISRegistration" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="Company" Name="Company">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Application" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="">
        <File Id="File1" Name="IISRegistration.txt" Source="IISRegistration.txt"></File>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

However, when I compile it with candle.exe I get the following error:

"error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.Platform)'"

BTW, I am using wix 3.11.
Is there any way I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code to the .wixproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <DefineConstants>
      $(DefineConstants);
      Platform=$(Platform)
   </DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```