# Wix MSI default installation location is 32bit instead of 64bit "Program Files (x86)"

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I created an MSI using WIx installer and its default installation location is showing as Program files instead of Program Files (x86)

App created in Visual studio Release mode x64

```
 Wix Code snippet 

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Manufacturer="X Tec" Description="Version 1.0" Comments="(C) 2020 X Tec" Platform="x64"/>

  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="MANUFACTURERDIR" Name="X Tec">
```

As "ProgramFiles64Folder" is give it should go in Program Files (x86), Do i miss something

Comment: Did the below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sample below, make sure your component is marked as 64-bit:

> The construct: **`$(env.SystemRoot)`** - in the WiX source below -
> gets the environment variable **`%SystemRoot%`** - which resolves to
> `C:\` on most systems (to list environment variables open a `cmd.exe`
> and type `set` and press `Enter`). The below source should hence
> compile on all systems without modifications (except you need to add a GUID for the UpgradeCode attribute):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*" Name="Sample" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0"
           Manufacturer="." UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes"
             InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Feature Id="MainFeature" Title="MainFeature" Level="1" />
    
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="MainApplicationFolder" Name="Main Application Folder">

          <!-- Using notepad.exe as sample file should compile on all systems -->
          <Component Feature="MainFeature" Win64="yes">
            <File Source="$(env.SystemRoot)\notepad.exe" />
          </Component>

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

---

***Links***:

- [How can I insert Intel64 or x64 in Template Summary in an MSI project of Wix Toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547214/how-can-i-insert-intel64-or-x64-in-template-summary-in-an-msi-project-of-wix-too/68547551#68547551)
- [Wix Toolset won't install WPF app in 64-bit Program Files Folder when the app is 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038704/wix-toolset-wont-install-wpf-app-in-64-bit-program-files-folder-when-the-app-is/64047446#64047446)
- [Fancy compiler variable use to be able to compile both x86 and x64-bit versions](https://github.com/mohdshine/R1/blob/c816a6740ae63e2c3065653539ea18b9c5edfce6/src/setup/iisnode-msi/iisnode.wxs).
- https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/
- [Using Wix to create 32bit and 64bit installers from one .wxs file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231950/using-wix-to-create-32bit-and-64bit-installers-from-one-wxs-file/6232100#6232100)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how it should work.  In a 64-bit Windows installation, the "Program Files" directory is where 64-bit applications should be installed.  The "Program Files (x86)" directory is for 32-bit applications.  The only time a 32-bit application should be installed into the "Program Files" directory is on a 32-bit Windows installation.  In that case, because all applications are 32-bit there is no need for a "Program Files (x86)" directory.

In summary:

| OS Version | 64-bit Applications | 32-bit Applications |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 64-bit Windows | C:\Program Files | C:\Program Files (x86) |
| 32-bit Windows | (n/a) | C:\Program Files |

See also: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/programs-files-vs-program-files-x86/7d631676-e688-472a-a1bb-eefccfeca6d7

Comment: Neat use of tables - haven't seen that before on the site.