# How can I insert Intel64 or x64 in Template Summary in an MSI project of Wix Toolkit?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, x86-64, program-files

I am writing a simple code to install a file in the `Program Files` folder, NOT `Program Files (x86)`

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Del">
                <Directory Id="MyFolder" Name="MyFolder"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <Component Id="Component1" Directory="MyFolder" Win64="yes">
       <File Id="FirstFile.txt"/>
    </Component>
</Fragment>
```

Basically it should create a folder `del` in `Program Files` and in it, it should create folder `MyFolder` which would contain `FirstFile.txt`

If I do it for `Id = ProgramFilesFolder` , it works by installing in `Program Files (x86)`

Changing it to `ProgramFiles64Folder` gives the following error

```
ICE80: This package contains 64 bit component 'Component1' but the Template Summary Property does not contain Intel64 or x64.
```

My Question is from where or how can I change the Template Summary property ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Arnson's Approach***: Do check out the answer from [Bob Arnson](https://twitter.com/barnson). Here is an extract from his blog: *"It’s typical to want to produce both 32-bit and 64-bit packages from the same WiX source, so a common approach is to make the @Win64 attribute value a [preprocessor variable](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html)."* Hence he uses a compiler switch to compile either x32 or x64-bit version MSI files from the same source.

And no: you can not support both with architectures with one MSI. See this blog from [Heath Stewart](https://twitter.com/mrhestew): [Different Packages are Required for Different Processor Architectures](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/).

---

***"Hard Coded" Way***: Here is an old sample you can try:
https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXBitnessX64

Some extracts:

***Package element***:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />
```

***Component element***:

```
<Component Feature="ProductFeature" Win64="yes">
  <File Source="$(env.SystemRoot)\notepad.exe" />
</Component>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Wix 4.0.2:

Add this to your `.wixproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
   <InstallerPlatform>x64</InstallerPlatform>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Make sure you have set `<StandardDirectory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">` and `Component.Bitness=always64` for all components

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! This fixed my V4 project!

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/05/14/working-hard-or-hardly-working/#manually-marking-package-and-component-bitness:

> Specify the -arch switch at the candle.exe command line or the InstallerPlatform property in a .wixproj MSBuild project. When you specify x64 or intel64, Candle automatically sets the package and components in the file being compiled as 64-bit.