# Pass command line variables into WiXx based Windows Installer MSI

Tags: wix, windows-installer, command-line-arguments

I am building an MSI installer with WiX and I am using the `WixUI_Advanced`. The definition of my `ApplicationFolder` looks like this, following the advice in another SO answer ([WiX tricks and tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/578340#578340)).

```
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="$(var.InstallName)">
```

I now want to give the user the option to do a silent install and pass the `ApplicationFolder` name on the path, either relative to the appropriate program files folder or absolute.

I know that I can pass public property values on the command-line of `msiexec,` but how do I use that as value for `ApplicationFolder` and how do I set this up for absolute vs relative paths.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You just define the property on the command line when running msiexec:

```
msiexec /i product.msi APPLICATIONFOLDER="C:\Program Files\Company\Product\"
```

The files will be installed into "C:\Program Files\Company\Product" directory.

I'd advice using *absolute path* here. A relative path may lead to unexpected results.

Comment: This works when I do a /quiet install, but when I do an interactive install and press the advanced button on the licence screen I do not see my specified APPLICATIONFOLDER show up in the directory selection dialog. I expect/want it to show up there as well.

Comment: @Jeroen I see. I can suggest using MSI verbose log to find why the value of APPLICATIONFOLDER is modified and where. Run your package as `msiexec /i package.msi /lv*x log.txt APPLICATIONFOLDER="C:\Program Files\Company\Product\"`. Then search the log for `APPLICATIONFOLDER`, you'll see when it's modified. (Sorry it took me a while.)