# c:\programme and c:\program files in SCCM environment

Tags: sccm

When installing a specific software (cheops) via SCCM to german PC's we are facing an issue with the language of the operating system.

It seems that the installpackage is searching for a map which is named "Program Files". 
On German staged pc's where the operating system is most of the time in German, the map is called "programme"

Is it possible that this might cause a problem?
How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

1. Complain to the software vendor.  They should be using environment variables rather than a hard-coded path.  Sigh... I suspect, though, that you don't have much control over that.
2. Many setup programs allow parameters to be passed via the command line. Perhaps you could pass a German-specific path for those users.  See [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16767/How-to-Pass-Command-Line-Arguments-to-MSI-Installe) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305301/pass-command-line-variables-into-wix-based-windows-installer-msi).