# Changing images at runtime on installer using WIX

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I am using WIX installer to develop installer.

I want to enhance the installer in terms of UI. I want to change the images at run-time on the same screen (not like billboard) like below
[image]

I have fixed 5 features. So there will be no scroll bar and all. I just want to show the current feature being installed and if any error occurs for particular feature red error icon should be displayed.

Is this possible using WIX

Answer (score 0):

You could probably put stack various images on top of each other and set the hide/show conditions based upon some kind of properties that says if the feature is installed/installing/errored

I'm not sure about doing this dynamically such that you could only have to code it for one feature and then it would apply to all features.

Seeings as you only have five features its probably easy to duplicate the code a few times but obviously this isn't a good idea in the long run in terms of maintainability

EDIT: you might be able to design a T4 template that would generate such a UI for you automatically, in this case the code essentially would still be duplicated but it would only exist once in the T4

See [WiX tricks and tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/1903533#1903533) for more on T4 generation

Comment: Can you please post some sample?

Comment: sorry been a while since I've used Wix