# How to avoid 'Win64' attribute is invalid when using variables in a WiX installer script?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

I have a WiX installer and I am following [wix-tricks-and-tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips)

My variables all work fine, but I am flooded with 100's of warnings due to this:

```
<Component Id="C.Content.2011.1.414" DiskId="1" Guid="MYGUID" Win64="$(var.Win64)" KeyPath="yes">
```

I receive the warning:

> Warning   1   The 'Win64' attribute is invalid - The value '$(var.Win64)' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi:YesNoType' - The '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24, cannot be included in a name.

yet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
  <?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
    <?define Win64 = "yes" ?>
    <?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFiles64Folder" ?>
  <?else ?>
    <?define Win64 = "no" ?>
    <?define PlatformProgramFilesFolder = "ProgramFilesFolder" ?>
  <?endif ?>
</Include>
```

clearly Win64 is yes/no... how do I avoid this warning?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually need to specify the Win64 attribute for the component? I followed the same post as you and thus got the same warning. Then I read the docs for the Component Win64 attribute, which indicate that the default value is taken from the architecture of the installer project itself. Thus I removed the attribute altogether to no ill effect.

Comment: Oh yeah! I remember I did read (and do) that, but then, later, backed out of some changes I made and forgot about it. Let me try making an installer real quick and see if things work out. :)

Comment: @DanielPratt You're indeed correct. If you'd like you can respond more formally and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: would this work better? 
`<?define Win64 = yes ?>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to just remove the Win64 variable altogether. Once you have your platform build targets setup properly WiX can just figure it out.