# WiX SourcePath for files

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I'm trying to create an installer that install's several discrete applications.
I would like to be about to create something like a variable, so i can use absolute paths

For something like the utilities library instead of typing `c:\Users\me\Documents\VS2012\Projects\Foo\Bar\bin\Release\Util.dll`

i would like to create a directory variable and type something like

`[FooBarRelease]\Util.dll`
Is that doable?

Comment: This SO answer has some info on using a .wxi file to contain variables which you can reference in your installer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/577793#577793

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a little about variables creation in wix:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/preprocessor.htm

what you need according to your example is described here:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/votive_project_references.htm

check out `$(var.MyProject.TargetName)`

Comment: $(var.MyProject.TargetDir) that is exactly what i was looking for