# How do you reference a ProjectName with a . in the name with WIX

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to add a file source using the project. But my project name has . in it:

```xml
<Component Guid="*">
  <File Source="$(var.Company.Product.Service.TargetPath" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

I get this error when trying to build:

`Error  1   Ill-formed preprocessor variable '$((var.Company.Product.Service.TargetPath)'.  Variables must have a prefix (like 'var.', 'env.', or 'sys.') and a name at least 1 character long. If the literal string '$((var.Company.Product.Service.TargetPath)' is desired, use '$$((var.Company.Product.Service.TargetPath)'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just lack end parenthesis:

```xml
<File Source="$(var.Company.Product.Service.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
```

See here for Wix tips and tricks: [WiX tricks and tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/577793#577793)

Comment: Doh! Nice catch. However, I get a new error:

Error 1 Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.Company.Product.Service.TargetPath)'.

Comment: Check the [**tips and tricks link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips/577793#577793). And [**this well known Wix tutorial**](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial). And [**this nice CodeProject quick-start, hands-on tutorial**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure exactly what I messed up. But I copied the ProjectName from the wixproj file and it worked.

Comment: You must use `<?define ProductName = "Product Name" ?>` somewhere to resolve the variable at compile time. [**See this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/578340/129130).