# Wix Installer of a Visualstudio multilanguage application

Tags: wix, multilingual, culture

I am designing a multilanguage application in C#. The project structure is shown here:

[image]

The form frmLogin use 3 resource files to get some controls text and labels frmLogin.*.resx which I would like to add in the wix project file.
The language is selected at runtime by a number of radio buttons.
I DO NOT want to have a multilanguage Wix installer, just a single installer which installs the required culture-elated dlls in the installation directory

I looked here [Add resource files in wix installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852401/add-resource-files-in-wix-installer) but it did not worked in my project
There is something obviously wrong in the wix project file since it does not create language directorys like this:

[image]

in the installation directory ...
I am sorry if I am missing something trivial but I am starting now with wix which looks very promising indeed but I am just starting now

many thanks

Comment: Can you share the complete Product WiX file?

Comment: Guessing from the picture you are missing the same thing as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43864566/2354418) is suggesting from your link. You need to have Directory attributes. Otherwise, I agree with Morten Frederiksen on seeing more information to help.

Comment: Here is the installer project https://www.dropbox.com/s/vt2z3gxgmqwtvh0/Installer.7z?dl=0. Thanks much

Comment: yes but if I add Directory="LOCALEEN" (or whatever) I get an error from Visual Studio ...

Comment: This is compile clean but still the 'en' and 'fr' directories are not created ... I guess there is a most concise way to do this but actually this is my best

Comment: I solved it by adding in the <feature> section <ComponentGroupRef Id="EnLocaleComponents" <ComponentGroupRef Id="FrLocaleComponents" />