# How to add .sql files to the .MSI Project file?

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I wrote a console app which to deploy scripts. App does all the script generate and deploy to the mapped database.  I am working on MSI Deployment package.

How to include .sql files to the .MSI Deployment Package? (or) How to include all dependent files to the MSI Deployment Package?

Comment: Have a look at wix [sql schema](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/sql/) It allows to deploy sql scripts and create database

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski , thanks.. it need not to be .sql file .. what about other dependent files .. , I have couple of utility project apps which we need to build MSI for them as well ...

Comment: Than have a look at basic wix [sample](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html) and [tips and tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471424/wix-tricks-and-tips)

Comment: Thanks , I opened up this posting for MSI deployment ... WIX .. i am okay with it .. but i need permission from my lead.. , it will be helpful to have some advice on MSI ..

Comment: Just quickly a link for you: [SqlScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426004/129130). Didn't read to thoroughly - in case I misunderstood. If all you want to do is to add the sql files to install to disk - though - just add them as regular MSI components. [**WiX quick start suggestions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) - look for the samples section? A bit down the page.