# changed component guid in MSI and it's causing issues

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I am working on the installer for a product (currently version 3). Between versions 1 and 2 (already released), the guid of a component was changed, but the keypath adn everything stayed the same (and needs to stay the same still). In version 3, I need to make a change to move RemoveExisitingProducts later in the install sequence. However, this is exposing a new bug causing the component that had its guid changed to not be installed if upgrading from version 1 to version 3. I'm trying to figure out a way around this bug. Repairing fixes the installation but I'd rather not have to repair. I think it'll probably take some kind of hack to fix it, but I haven't been successful. I tried going to HKLM/Microsoft/windows/currentversion/installer/user data/S-15-18/components/OLDPACKEDGUID and deleting it before running the new installer, but that seems to cause terrible issues and be much worse.

anyone know a solution to this issue, even if it's a big hack?
Thanks

Comment: Can't you change the component GUID to its previous value? Was it changed intentionally?

Comment: then upgrading from version 2 to version 3 would cause issues.

Comment: I must have read the question incorrectly as if the GUID was changed between versions 2 and 3. In this case, I'm afraid there's no work around the issue but scheduling `RemoveExisitingProducts` early enough. Although I have another crazy idea: add component with the removed GUID back so that the files in question are in two components, I'm pretty sure this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to schedule `RemoveExistingProducts` earlier in the sequence so that during upgrade the previous product is completely uninstalled before installing the new product.

Also look at this [WiX upgrade question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870405/wix-upgrade-question-files-major-version-was-incremented-but-revision-is-lowe/6873392#6873392). And [another one may](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227456/windows-installer-deletes-versioned-file-during-product-upgrade-instead-of-downg) also be helpful.