# Wix Installer Specifying a TARGETDIR

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm writing a Wix installer and one of the requirements is that the user can specify a target directory.  Now, I'm very unfamiliar with Wix and so am trying to get my head around how it works.  Ordinarily, a user specifying an installation directory seems fairly simple, so this is what I've done:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="PlatformProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="foo" Name ="foo">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="bar" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

So, if the user on the command line specifies a INSTALLFOLDER it will use that rather than the default install path.  However, they specifically want to use the name **TARGETDIR** as the variable for specifying the target install directory as below:

```
msiexec /i foobar.msi TARGETDIR=C:\foo\bar\
```

Now TARGETDIR is predefined, so you can't just use it as a replacement for INSTALLFOLDER.  So is there a way that I can make this work or am I just missing something very stupidly simple?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003336/what-is-the-usage-of-targetdir-and-installdir-in-wix)

Comment: Will have a look later. Lobbing you some links for now: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641094/in-wix-files-what-does-name-sourcedir-refer-to), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561165/129130), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52731065/129130), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401425/129130). I think TARGETDIR is used for [administrative installations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130), and INSTALLFOLDER for regular installation, but I have honestly not checked in detail.

Comment: Just for reference, MSI expert Chris Painter: [How to define installation folder from command line parameter in Wix installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266720/how-to-define-installation-folder-from-command-line-parameter-in-wix-installer) and [WiX mailing list](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Setting-installation-location-from-command-line-td5828080.html).

Comment: Actually you can solely use `TARGETDIR` to define your installation folder. The `INSTALLFOLDER` seen in most examples is superfluous, it just simplifies the examples a little bit. You need a custom action to set the default path though.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul You're totally missing the point with your links.  It's *NOT* about setting the installation folder on the command line, that's easy.  It's about setting the installation folder **specifically** with TARGETDIR.