# WIX Setup Bootstrapper: Calling the msi with command line arguments

Tags: wix

I use use the Wix Installer to create a setup for my application.
I use the Bootstrapper for the Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 runtimes,
so I get a setup.exe and a product.msi.
Now I try to use the Minor Update mechanism, like described here:
[How to implement WiX installer upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade)

For the minor Update I have to rum the Installer with this command:

```
msiexec /i SampleUpgrade.msi REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus
```

How can I pass the parameter the msiexec if the user calls the setup.exe?

Comment: The linked questions only mentions Major upgrades, it doesn't mention minor upgrades or the properties mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrapper should contain the logic that determines what installers are called when. So you'll need to call msiexec yourself from within the bootstrapper.