# Upgrade with Wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I tried nearly all solutions list on page [How to implement WiX installer upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade/7802315) , but didn't upgrade successful. always prompt this message when I was upgrade:

"Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel."

When I trace the installer log, it shows:

Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.
{CCA05551-C990-4ACA-9B01-A65AA9FBF884}
MSI (c) (50:40) [13:49:33:462]: Product:  -- Configuration failed.

MSI (c) (50:40) [13:49:33:462]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name:  Product Version: 2.0.1.6. Product Language: 1033. Reconfiguration success or error status: 1638.

---

Any configuration I missed?

Comment: Solved, two notes: 1) ProductCode need to change, 2), only the last version changed won't work, e.g. from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a package perform a major upgrade you must increase its [ProductVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and change the [ProductCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370854%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

You can read about different types of upgrades here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yes, I changed the Version every time I build MSI, but I have question about ProductCode, if we changed this value, how to installer detect the related product?

Comment: it works after ProductCode changed. still don't understand how installer detect related products?

Comment: @Cooper.Wu, it uses the `UpgradeCode`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372399(v=vs.85).aspx