# How can I uninstall my app using an upgraded MSI file created in WIX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way i can uninstall (and dont upgrade after) a previous version of my app, using an upgraded MSI (created in WIX)?

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802965/upgrade-with-wix

Comment: Thanks, saw these already, but still missing the point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the part with:

> and dont upgrade after

I haven't see this done before. Why don't you just use the MSI from the original application to launch the uninstall?

If you want a simple double click package that performs the uninstall you can create an executable, doesn't matter the programming language, that executes this:

```
msiexec /x {..<product code>..}
```

Comment: I'd like to have an Uninstall opton inside the upgraded MSI, so i dont know what shall i modify in WIX to achieve RemoveExistingProducts, then skipping install.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why you can't use the old version MSI for the uninstall. Can you explain more on that?  I ask this because its not recommended and standard practice to create an MSI that removes and older version but doesn't install anything else, i.e. a newer version.