# How specify a custom action to only run for upgrading from certain version in a windows installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way to check for the product version that windows installer is upgrading from, such that, a specified custom action only runs on upgrades from certain versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create a file search that will check for a specific version and set a property you can use in your custom action condition. See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_the_version_number.htm for a nice guide.

Answer (score 1):

You need to defined your upgrade rule, using a a custom public property, here are more details: [How to implement WiX installer upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade)
Then use this property to create the condition desired.