# MSI custom action installer state interaction

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, state, custom-action

I've got a custom action that runs a UI after the [.msi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) deploys files. This UI sets the configuration and also deploys various things to various places (SQL servers, etc..). The UI itself is running in [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) ([.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 2.0). How could I possibly get the state of the installer (that is, upgrade/install/repair and silent/minimalUI/fullUI, etc..)?

Basically, how can I access what mode the installer is in from custom UI based in C#/.NET 2 so that I can handle those states in my code?

(This is similar to Stack Overflow question *[How to add a WiX custom action that happens only on uninstall (via MSI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320921/how-to-add-a-wix-custom-action-that-happens-only-on-uninstall-via-msi)*, but not quite.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass the values of the properties as parameters to your custom action that give you this information. The "[Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" property is set only if the package is running in maintenance (modify or remove). To differentiate between modify and remove these you can have check "[REMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" property. Here is a list with the conditions you need to build inside your custom action.

1. Condition for **install**: NOT Installed
2. Condition for **uninstall**: REMOVE="ALL"
3. Condition for **maintenance**: Installed AND REMOVE<>"ALL"

For upgrading, you need to use the property that you defined to be set if an older version is defined. Assuming you have used this method from Stack Oveflow question *[How to implement WiX installer upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade/4587685#4587685)*.

For the UI level of the package you can check the property [UILevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That looks like it could be a viable option (rather than creating a new custom action and new, disjointed code for the installer. The only problem being delving into WiX (But I suspected I'd have to do that anyway)